# Using the same certificate with a windows service and an ASP.NET MVC web application (in IIS)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ssl, windows-services, certificate

Is it possible to use the same SSL certificate for a windows service and an ASP.NET MVC application in IIS.

Both the Windows service and the MVC app are hosted on a Windows Server 2008 machine with IIS 7.

The MVC web is accessed with www.mydomain.com, and the services are accesed through ip_address/myService/method...

Comment: UPDATE: I've just started using the services with the URL: https://www.mydomain.com/service/myService/method...

Sience the web and the service are on the same ip adress (the same machine), the url www.mydomain.com points to the web and the services. In that way the same certificate can be used for both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SSL Certs are tied to domain names, not IP address.  So I belive the answer to your question is no.

See:

[ip based ssl certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2854805/ip-based-ssl-certificate)