# SSL Certificate expiration date is wrong (X509Certificate.getNotAfter()

Tags: java, ssl

I need to verify is specific site is signed properly with SSL Certificate. 
For my problem I used code found here: [Writing a SSL Checker using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8545685/writing-a-ssl-checker-using-java)

I wanted to check the expiration date on https://testssl-expire.disig.sk/.

Unfortunately the `serverCert.getNotAfter();` method gives me the wrong date.

Any ideas why this date is not accurate?

Comment: How much wrong is "wrong"?

Comment: Show us your code, show us the certificate - probably its not a secret right? :)

Comment: Code is exactly the same as I linek in the post. It should give me expiration date 23.07.2012 lub it gives 23.07.2015 ;) You can check the certificate in your web browser.

Comment: I am still curious why this dosn't work but in the mean time I used other way to check is there an secure SSL connection. http://paste.org/69956.