# How to add subject alternative name to ssl certs?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, x509certificate, keytool

I'm using *openssl* to create self-signed certs. I'm getting this error with the certs I generated:

> javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:
>   java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative names
>   present

Does anyone know how to specify "Subject alternative name" while creating a cert?
This is how I'm generating a keystore:

```
sudo $JAVA_HOME/bin/keytool -genkey -dname "CN=192.168.x.xxx, OU=I, O=I, L=T, ST=On, C=CA" -alias tomcat -validity 3650 -keyalg RSA -keystore /root/.keystore -keypass abcd -storepass abcd
```

To generate a key:

```
 openssl s_client -connect 192.168.x.xxx:8443 2>/dev/null
```

Please help! Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How are SSL certificate server names resolved/Can I add alternative names using keytool?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8443081/how-are-ssl-certificate-server-names-resolved-can-i-add-alternative-names-using)

Comment: @ Sapphire: I don't understand your problem. The Subject Alternative Name is `NOT` a required extension in X.509 certificate.So if you have a certificate without it, there is no problem. So how are you getting this exception?

Comment: @user384706 Can you please look at this question? Even I'm confused about why it is throwing this error. [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8759956/failed-to-create-service-exception-javax-xml-ws-webserviceexception/8760118#8760118]

Comment: @Sapphire: Replied in the other thread

Comment: The accepted answer is in Java.  To do this with OpenSSL, here's an answer: http://security.stackexchange.com/a/91556

Comment: In response to @Cratylus' comment from early 2012, Chrome now no longer accepts the Common Name and requires the SAN field. (In the short term a config change can revert to the old behavior. That setting will be removed eventually, forcing SAN adoption.)

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Although [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8444863/372643) was more specifically about IP addresses in Subject Alt. Names, the commands are similar (using `DNS` entries for a host name and `IP` entries for IP addresses).

To quote myself:

> If you're using `keytool`, as of [Java 7, keytool](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/keytool.html) has an option to
>   include a Subject Alternative Name (see the table in the documentation
>   for -ext): you could use -ext san=dns:www.example.com or -ext
>   san=ip:10.0.0.1

Note that you only need Java 7's `keytool` to use this command. Once you've prepared your keystore, it should work with previous versions of Java.

(The rest of this answer also mentions how to do this with OpenSSL, but it doesn't seem to be what you're using.)

Comment: I can't change to Java7. Is there a way to bypass the subjectalternativename check in my Java code?

Comment: Don't avoid this check. As I said, you only need Java 7 to use this `keytool` command. Once it's done, you should be able to use the JKS file with your Java 6 (or lower) installation (it doesn't even have to be on the same machine). Alternatively, you could use OpenSSL to generate this (self-signed) certificate (the commands and settings might be a bit more complex): you could turn your PEM key/cert generated with OpenSSL into a `.p12` file and use it directly from Java as a keystore using keystore type `PKCS12`. You could also use a hostname instead of an IP addr: you'd get away with the CN.

Comment: I used a hostname instead like you suggested and I got this: No name matching myhostname.com found.

Comment: Well, you need to use a host name that's configured to match that IP address (in DNS or hosts file). If you're not familiar with those concepts, it sounds like installing Java 7 somewhere might be the easiest solution for you.

Comment: I updated the /etc/hosts file with "myip    myhostname" and used myhostname in the certificate.

Comment: with most keytool commands accepting an extension (`genkeypair`, `gencert`, and `gencertreq`) it is unclear to me how the propagation happens. my assumption is that this is an ever increasing list that gets chained? but i also realise that using the ext in `genkeypair` for the purposes of creating a signing request won't include the subject alternative names

Answer (score 43):

Both IP and DNS can be specified with the keytool additional argument `-ext SAN=dns:abc.com,ip:1.1.1.1`

Example:

```
keytool -genkeypair -keystore <keystore> -dname "CN=test, OU=Unknown, O=Unknown, L=Unknown, ST=Unknown, C=Unknown" -keypass <keypwd> -storepass <storepass> -keyalg RSA -alias unknown -ext SAN=dns:test.abc.com,ip:1.1.1.1
```

Comment: Beware that the above command does **not** create a CSR. Java's keytool creates a keypair in the form of a self-signed certificate in the key store, and the SAN attribute goes into that self-signed certificate. If you want to issue a CSR with a SAN attribute, you need to pass the same -ext argument to 'keytool -certreq'. Funny thing is that the self-documenting help of keytool does **not** include the -ext option, although keytool does process -ext just fine.

Comment: @avarvit this means that I may add altNames in the CSR even if these are not used invoking `-genkeypair`. What would happen when receiving a certificate from the CA with this CSR? Woule keytool import it and link to the correct private key? Is this a possibile way to add altName to certificates that missed it?

Comment: Thanks for adding a full example

Answer (score 13):

When generating CSR is possible to specify **-ext** attribute again to have it inserted in the CSR

```
keytool -certreq -file test.csr -keystore test.jks -alias testAlias -ext SAN=dns:test.example.com
```

complete example here: [How to create CSR with SANs using keytool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30755220/how-to-create-csr-with-sans-using-keytool/43637750#43637750)