# No subject alternative names present exception when creating web service client

Tags: java, ssl, ssl-certificate, apache-axis, wsdl2java

I want to create a web service client using wsdl2java utility. 
I have to connect to this server over SSL

This wsdl looks like this:

```
https://xxx.xx.xx.xx:8443/api/wsdl/xxxxxxx.wsdl
```

I generated the certificate using:

```
openssl s_client -connect xxx.xx.xx.x:8443 </dev/null | sed -ne '/-BEGIN CERTIFICATE-/,/-END CERTIFICATE-/p' > abcCertificate.pem
```

and added it to keystore using:

```
keytool -import -noprompt -trustcacerts -alias testcert -file abcCertificate.pem -keystore /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_06/jre/lib/security/cacerts -ext san=ip:xxx.xx.xx.xx
```

When I try to use `wsdl2java` to create the *web service* client, it *throws exception*:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative names present
```

I use these information 
[from this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8744607/how-to-add-subject-alernative-name-to-ssl-certs/8744717#8744717).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How are SSL certificate server names resolved/Can I add alternative names using keytool?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8443081/how-are-ssl-certificate-server-names-resolved-can-i-add-alternative-names-using)

Comment: I've used `NoopHostnameVerifier`, see  https://stackoverflow.com/a/57746053/548473

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be confused between "importing" and "generating" the certificate.

You `openssl s_client` command doesn't generate the certificate, it retrieves the certificate in use on that server.

The `keytool -import` command you use afterwards imports that certificate, as it is, into your truststore. There is no point using `-ext san=ip:xxx.xx.xx.xx` there: you're not generating the certificate, you're only importing it.

If you're in control of that server, you should generate (or get a certificate from somewhere else) with an IP address SAN (since [Java follows the specification strictly on this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8444863/372643)).

If you're not in control of that server, use its host name (provided that there is at least a CN matching that host name in the existing cert).

In general, it's not great to import directly a certificate obtained solely from a server like this into your trust store, since you're assuming that that particular connection wasn't tampered with.

Comment: If I'm not in the control of the server, what exactly can I do in order to avoid the problem of the topic starter? I posted a description of what I did here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19540289/how-to-fix-the-java-security-cert-certificateexception-no-subject-alternative .