# Java CertificateException "No subject alternative names matching IP address ... found"

Tags: java, ssl, ip, certificate

I'm trying to implement a selfsigned certificate into my webserver, and it's working already with firefox and chrome (both from the server itself and from a remote machine)... but I can't get it to work with java. I've already created a keystore file that contains my certificate, but every time I try to connect to the Server it gives me a SSLHandshakeException: `javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative names matching IP address 192.168.178.71 found`

The code I'm using for this test is:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
         System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore",                    HTTPStest.class.getResource("keystore.jks").getFile());
            System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword",           "lead"); 
        URL url;
            InputStream is = null;
            BufferedReader br;
            String line;

            try {
                url = new URL("https://192.168.178.71/");
                is = url.openStream();  // throws an IOException
                br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println(line);
                }
            } catch (MalformedURLException mue) {
                 mue.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException ioe) {
                 ioe.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                try {
                    if (is != null) is.close();
                } catch (IOException ioe) {
                    // nothing to see here
                }
            }

    }
```

And when checking my certificate with openssl it gives me this:

```
 Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number: 2 (0x2)
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: C=DE, ST=BY, L=MU, O=LEAD, CN=LEAD CA/emailAddress=test@gmail.com
        Validity
            Not Before: Mar 20 00:55:13 2015 GMT
            Not After : Mar 17 00:55:13 2025 GMT
        Subject: C=DE, ST=BY, L=BE, CN=192.168.178.71
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
                Public-Key: (2048 bit)
                Modulus:
                    00:ed:9b:27:2b:ab:7d:88:48:a3:21:54:98:24:be:
                    2d:72:4a:de:9c:05:de:95:3a:01:d5:46:09:d2:9c:
                    9f:29:b0:12:0c:86:28:88:51:a3:b9:c9:93:33:3c:
                    8a:5c:f2:fe:49:e2:1e:9e:5a:4b:fb:63:41:9a:13:
                    e5:bc:03:77:a0:5e:f2:b1:1f:db:f9:a4:03:07:8c:
                    41:54:8c:bc:2e:da:cd:72:67:5b:2f:d5:83:fd:d0:
                    bf:ea:bb:49:e0:21:2f:b3:f2:51:57:7c:81:d2:4b:
                    91:12:73:13:6a:29:3b:59:90:2d:8d:50:cc:2b:f2:
                    76:a8:41:ac:0a:11:8b:63:3b:d4:5c:91:5c:1e:41:
                    33:6f:3e:fe:ed:f4:c3:26:77:d9:e2:0b:2c:09:5c:
                    20:31:09:59:19:5c:15:75:eb:15:ef:b8:d8:7d:a2:
                    2d:f4:f8:7f:3a:7c:e0:ad:c0:3b:86:1e:4f:b1:b9:
                    c3:60:f8:fa:3c:5a:5a:72:bf:f9:95:c3:d4:8d:2b:
                    22:3f:f8:a2:37:b3:c2:16:fa:9e:2d:f9:b5:78:6d:
                    4f:88:95:84:12:f3:f5:c2:09:9f:51:ed:73:da:4d:
                    9b:c3:2f:99:6d:d7:e9:f3:e0:c4:8b:73:09:25:1f:
                    93:5c:dc:d7:fa:5c:47:59:ff:70:70:09:72:4a:8c:
                    3f:c5
                Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Subject Key Identifier: 
                FD:5F:79:74:31:E3:12:22:50:F8:C5:BE:A7:45:8B:10:65:8F:FC:A8
            X509v3 Authority Key Identifier: 
                keyid:C5:2F:3A:53:A7:AF:96:E2:25:09:46:8A:11:B6:B9:5D:79:55:04:D9

            X509v3 Basic Constraints: 
                CA:FALSE
            X509v3 Key Usage: 
                Digital Signature, Key Encipherment
            X509v3 Subject Alternative Name: 
                DNS:192.168.178.71, DNS:www.example.com, DNS:mail.example.com, DNS:ftp.example.com
            Netscape Comment: 
                OpenSSL Generated Certificate
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
         7a:17:44:18:8e:31:11:b9:0a:fc:bf:d2:61:2f:16:24:56:24:
         11:04:9e:2e:dc:65:d1:31:12:af:3d:ff:57:80:6b:45:70:f2:
         e3:d8:2d:dd:d1:1d:05:ba:2e:92:d1:80:e8:93:0c:02:b2:47:
         d1:5c:10:54:cb:4d:e5:52:f4:1d:c4:d2:26:a5:8e:4c:a3:44:
         c0:6a:1d:74:27:89:6f:f4:dc:90:cc:3b:59:50:b7:38:5b:31:
         da:21:01:d4:e6:4f:7a:23:23:d5:c5:61:29:32:1a:1e:bb:f9:
         e1:3b:4f:a9:d8:d6:1d:f5:cf:15:04:18:8b:77:28:44:ef:ae:
         33:8c:1e:72:d6:8c:c4:cc:7c:17:b8:f4:e5:d0:34:4f:d5:3d:
         d7:59:4d:40:f3:42:1e:0c:26:98:73:98:a5:c2:d9:ea:2b:2a:
         05:c3:f5:0b:e1:b6:d7:91:4a:09:15:21:1b:bc:d1:96:5e:bd:
         47:9f:ab:27:e9:44:fc:00:e1:49:e4:74:1b:48:ff:56:01:03:
         e7:9b:d2:bc:0a:53:39:95:52:5f:de:d8:fe:10:e8:53:5f:b4:
         de:18:2d:50:a4:12:f8:48:37:66:4b:e1:18:21:69:ce:f3:0d:
         2f:3d:03:22:bf:f6:91:3f:23:0b:58:4f:5f:be:82:67:ab:65:
         98:15:e0:78:33:c6:50:38:39:42:ac:a5:bd:13:16:ca:58:64:
         ce:a7:e8:88:e8:2f:eb:d5:7e:9e:75:51:da:50:b4:41:d1:83:
         a8:a8:a3:18:25:b8:87:9d:c8:18:a0:db:7a:57:b1:31:e3:34:
         a8:92:b7:4b:75:c4:34:09:3d:a2:de:69:b2:d5:2f:9e:97:b7:
         c8:b5:df:8a:a8:d8:e2:b0:96:9e:56:39:40:c5:64:bf:fb:b2:
         b8:cb:e1:29:24:a7:ce:00:34:d6:a9:11:c4:bf:8e:ae:c8:5c:
         50:38:42:b9:15:9e:db:6b:00:ff:93:e8:0a:d3:00:13:0a:31:
         3b:cc:93:ad:92:09:9d:97:dd:42:28:07:43:91:39:86:2e:54:
         97:4a:a6:57:96:07:69:90:62:58:eb:0b:39:44:05:74:ad:f5:
         bc:6a:41:5e:79:dd:27:99:32:67:c3:82:14:df:4b:44:a9:7e:
         63:29:4e:c3:a3:ef:fa:1d:14:da:54:77:fb:6c:d8:c6:cc:5f:
         99:06:38:f0:2c:78:41:f7:a1:5a:d6:29:1d:5f:df:f9:3b:7b:
         cf:9f:73:f3:6c:b4:cf:0b:8e:39:7a:f1:35:3e:8d:66:12:4f:
         f4:b1:04:6c:1f:d6:27:75:91:43:82:a4:74:a8:77:84:f9:ca:
         14:71:8a:ac:da:3b:39:2d
```

Can anyone help me solve this problem? I know that I could just go for a hostname, but I would like to have it work this way too

Comment: For Spring Boot `RestTemplate` see https://stackoverflow.com/a/59317106/548473

Comment: I have this problem in Docker because the IP addresses are randomly assigned to the container. Does anybody have a solution for this situation?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your certificate should include that ip value as a subject alternative name value (of type IPAddress : key=7).

http://web.archive.org/web/20160201235032/http://www.jroller.com/hasant/entry/no_subject_alternative_names_matching

Comment: Could you please elaborate, where should I add key=7? thanks!

Answer (score 12):

The reason why this fails is because the hostname of the target endpoint and the certificate common name (`CN` in certification `Subject` does not match).

For e.g., from a JVM, when trying to connect to an IP address (`WW.XX.YY.ZZ`) and not the DNS name (https://stackoverflow.com), the HTTPS connection will fail because the certificate stored in the java truststore `cacerts` expects common name to match the target address.

To mitigate this HostnameVerifier needs to be verify the connection despite the mismatch
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html#HostnameVerifier

```
    HttpsURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) new URL("https://test.test/api").openConnection();
    urlConnection.setSSLSocketFactory(buildSocketFactory());
    urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
    urlConnection.setRequestMethod("get");
    urlConnection.setHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
        @Override
        public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession sslSession) {
            return true;
        }
    });
    urlConnection.getOutputStream();
```

Comment: What is the value of `buildSocketFactory()`?

Answer (score 4):

The reason, we get above error is that CN(Common name) defined in your certificate is not matching with the domain the application is running on.
For e.g, In your certificate, the CN name is defined as www.example.com or an IP but you may be running the application say a URL which is like http://localhost:8080/api

So to fix the above error simply use one of the below approaches

Run the application on the same ‘CN’, as defined in your certificates.

OR

Along with CN name you can add Subject alt names in your certificate, which is like adding more than one domain in the certificate. Link below describes the process of adding multiple domains(subject-alt-name) to jks file and also to a certificate.

Follow this link: [Learn how to add subject alt names and resolve the above error](http://www.littlebigextra.com/how-to-add-subject-alt-names-or-multiple-domains-in-a-key-store-and-self-signed-certificate/)

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem so sharing my experience. These values should be same.

Take the CN value of the certificate and save into /etc/hosts and try to access it with this URI. It will work

[image]

Answer (score 0):

## Execute the following steps

1- Modify the file: /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf, for example:

```
subjectAltName=DNS:api.electoralsystem
```

2- Generate private key

```
jmendoza@jmendoza:~$ openssl genrsa -aes256 -out electoralsystem-cakey.pem 2048 -alias electoralsystem-cakey.pem
Generating RSA private key, 2048 bit long modulus
....................+++++
.......................................+++++
e is 65537 (0x010001)
Enter pass phrase for electoralsystem-cakey.pem:
Verifying - Enter pass phrase for electoralsystem-cakey.pem:
```

3- Generate cacert x509

```
jmendoza@jmendoza:~$ openssl req -new -x509 -sha256 -key electoralsystem-cakey.pem -days 365 -out electoralsystem-cacert.pem 
Enter pass phrase for electoralsystem-cakey.pem:
You are about to be asked to enter information that will be incorporated
into your certificate request.
What you are about to enter is what is called a Distinguished Name or a DN.
There are quite a few fields but you can leave some blank
For some fields there will be a default value,
If you enter '.', the field will be left blank.
-----
Country Name (2 letter code) [AU]:VE
State or Province Name (full name) [Some-State]:CARACAS
Locality Name (eg, city) []:CARACAS
Organization Name (eg, company) [Internet Widgits Pty Ltd]:JMENDOZA
Organizational Unit Name (eg, section) []:TI
Common Name (e.g. server FQDN or YOUR name) []:api.electoralsystem
Email Address []:xxxx@gmail.com
```

[openssl x509 -in electoralsystem-cacert.pem -text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1o7rT.png)

4- Generate keystore pkcs12

```
jmendoza@jmendoza:~$ openssl pkcs12 -export -in electoralsystem-cacert.pem -inkey electoralsystem-cakey.pem -out electoralsystem-store.p12 -name "electoralsystem-store" 
Enter pass phrase for electoralsystem-cakey.pem:
Enter Export Password:
Verifying - Enter Export Password:
```

5- If you need it, convert the PKCS12 keystore to JKS keytstore using keytool command

```
jmendoza@jmendoza:~$ keytool -importkeystore -destkeystore electoralsystem-store.jks -deststorepass jmendoza -srckeystore electoralsystem-store.p12 -srcstoretype PKCS12 -srcstorepass jmendoza -alias electoralsystem-store
Importando el almacén de claves de electoralsystem-store.p12 a electoralsystem-store.jks...
```

6- On the client, import certificate in keytstore

```
jmendoza@jmendoza:~$ keytool -importcert -file electoralsystem-cacert.pem -keystore ldap-server-smmt.jks 
Introduzca la contraseña del almacén de claves:
```

[Import certificate in keytstore](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JV5oJ.png)

Invoke API - https://api.electoralsystem:8081/yyyy/xxxxx

7- Configure certificates on the api server

[Configure certificates on the api server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y0FXL.png)

8- Summary generated files

```
jmendoza@jmendoza:~$ ls -lt
total 1332
-rw-rw-r--  1 jmendoza jmendoza    2482 jul 25 10:15  ldap-server-smmt.jks
-rw-r--r--  1 jmendoza jmendoza    2442 jul 25 10:04  electoralsystem-store.jks
-rw-------  1 jmendoza jmendoza    2792 jul 25 10:01  electoralsystem-store.p12
-rw-r--r--  1 jmendoza jmendoza    1509 jul 25 09:45  electoralsystem-cacert.pem
-rw-------  1 jmendoza jmendoza    1766 jul 25 09:38  electoralsystem-cakey.pem
```

Note: configure DNS api.electoralsystem on the client's docker or server

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the said

> javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative names matching IP address

error by adding one alternative subject name (DNS) in the server certificate (having CN=example.com) which after prints the part of certificate as below:

```
Subject Alternative Name:
DNS: example.com
```

I used KeyExplorer on windows for generating my server certificate. You can follow [this link](https://support.microfocus.com/kb/doc.php?id=7023489) for adding alternative subject names (follow the only part for adding it).

Answer (score 0):

1. import .cert using keytool (java):

```
- listar: keytool -list -v -keystore cacerts
- importar: keytool -importcert -file your-cert.crt -keystore cacerts -alias "ldap cert"
```

2. Verify JAVA_HOME is the same as keytool under you run the code
3. The hostname or domain in your .cert must be equals as the domain server
4. you must be valid a cert using a tool to confirm the name of the .cert, for example, this is a command using windows:

   `- CheckSSLCert.exe yourserverip [port]`
5. the code:

```
public DirContext dirContext(String currentPassword, String distinguishedName) throws Exception {
        log.info("getConnection configuration");
        try {
            Hashtable<String, String> env = new Hashtable<>();
            String keystore = System.getProperty("java.home") + System.getProperty("file.separator") + "lib" + System.getProperty("file.separator") + "security" + System.getProperty("file.separator") + "cacerts";
            System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", keystore);
            env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
            env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldaps://yourserverldap.hostname:636");
            env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
            env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "your ldap user");
            env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "your pass");
            env.put(Context.SECURITY_PROTOCOL, "ssl");
            return new InitialDirContext(env);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.info("error " + e.getMessage());
            throw e;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue while accessing the API via IP address.
So if you are in a position like me where you cannot make much changes in the code or the certificate itself, then you can simply add the CN name in your host file.
So in windows operating system, I edited the following file

```
C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts
```

and added following entry in it

```
10.10.10.10    xyz.domain.com
```

The domain name can be found in the CN in the certificate by hitting the the IP address in the browser.
[image]

If the CN name is like *.domain.com, then you can set the domain name as per your convenience such as abc.domain.com

But as per my opinion, this should be done only for local testing. The production environments should have the proper domain- address called instead of an IP address.

Answer (score 0):

This error kept driving me crazy, until after I decided to watch Netflix and blow off some mental steam. I came back to my laptop, and the first thought that dropped in my mind was to check on my domain name with my hosting service provider. It turned out my domain name had expired and all I had to do was to renew my subcription.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using ip address as your url.
You can try using FQDN in the url