# Server access Error: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative DNS name matching repo1.maven.org found

Tags: maven, sbt

I am doing: sbt clean and I started getting the following errors:

Server access Error: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative DNS name matching repo1.maven.org found

This worked as recently as a few hours back. How do I fix this issue? I cannot do a build.

Comment: See this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19540289/how-to-fix-the-java-security-cert-certificateexception-no-subject-alternative

Answer (score 3):

For anyone getting this problem recently, there's currently a bug with the maven repo ssl certificates:  https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/MVNCENTRAL-2870

Comment: ow.. still open after 1 year

Answer (score 0):

I have spent a day working on this problem, and finally found out it is a recent problem mentioned by @mienaikoe. my workaround here is to create in file ~/.sbt/repositories url link

```
[repositories]
local
secured-central: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2
```