# Disable hostname verification in io.netty.handler.ssl.Sslcontext

Tags: java, ssl, netty, asynchttpclient

Is there a way to disable hostname verification for io.netty.handler.ssl.Sslcontext?

I have this code:

```
sslContext = SslContextBuilder
        .forClient()
        .sslProvider(SslProvider.JDK)
        .trustManager(InsecureTrustManagerFactory.INSTANCE)
        .build();

DefaultAsyncHttpClientConfig.Builder builder = new DefaultAsyncHttpClientConfig.Builder();
builder.setSslContext(sslContext);
AsyncHttpClientConfig asyncHttpClientConfig = builder.build();
```

This works great with localhost trusting all certificates but I need to connect to a local ip to do some tests on a service and I'm getting this exception:

```
java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: java.net.ConnectException: General SSLEngine problem
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.encodeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:292)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:308)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniApply(CompletableFuture.java:593)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniApply.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:577)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:474)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeExceptionally(CompletableFuture.java:1977)
    at org.asynchttpclient.netty.NettyResponseFuture$1.run(NettyResponseFuture.java:269)
    at org.asynchttpclient.netty.NettyResponseFuture$2.execute(NettyResponseFuture.java:277)
    at org.asynchttpclient.future.ExecutionList.executeListener(ExecutionList.java:125)
    at org.asynchttpclient.future.ExecutionList.execute(ExecutionList.java:115)
    at org.asynchttpclient.future.AbstractListenableFuture.runListeners(AbstractListenableFuture.java:80)
    at org.asynchttpclient.netty.NettyResponseFuture.abort(NettyResponseFuture.java:252)
    at org.asynchttpclient.netty.channel.NettyConnectListener.onFailure(NettyConnectListener.java:162)
    at org.asynchttpclient.netty.channel.NettyConnectListener$1.onFailure(NettyConnectListener.java:131)
    at org.asynchttpclient.netty.SimpleFutureListener.operationComplete(SimpleFutureListener.java:26)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:514)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners0(DefaultPromise.java:507)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListenersNow(DefaultPromise.java:486)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:427)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.tryFailure(DefaultPromise.java:129)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.notifyHandshakeFailure(SslHandler.java:1235)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.setHandshakeFailure(SslHandler.java:1230)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.setHandshakeFailure(SslHandler.java:1205)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1060)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:900)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:411)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:248)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:366)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:345)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1294)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:366)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:911)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:131)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:611)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:552)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:466)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:438)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:140)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:144)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: General SSLEngine problem
    at org.asynchttpclient.netty.channel.NettyConnectListener.onFailure(NettyConnectListener.java:160)
    ... 29 common frames omitted
    Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: General SSLEngine problem
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.checkThrown(Handshaker.java:1431)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.checkTaskThrown(SSLEngineImpl.java:535)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readNetRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:813)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.unwrap(SSLEngineImpl.java:781)
    at javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.unwrap(SSLEngine.java:624)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1094)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:966)
    ... 18 common frames omitted
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: General SSLEngine problem
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.fatal(SSLEngineImpl.java:1728)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:304)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:296)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1509)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:216)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:979)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker$1.run(Handshaker.java:919)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker$1.run(Handshaker.java:916)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker$DelegatedTask.run(Handshaker.java:1369)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.runDelegatedTasks(SslHandler.java:1120)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1005)
    ... 18 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative names present
    at sun.security.util.HostnameChecker.matchIP(HostnameChecker.java:144)
    at sun.security.util.HostnameChecker.match(HostnameChecker.java:93)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkIdentity(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:455)
    at sun.security.ssl.AbstractTrustManagerWrapper.checkAdditionalTrust(SSLContextImpl.java:998)
    at sun.security.ssl.AbstractTrustManagerWrapper.checkServerTrusted(SSLContextImpl.java:937)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1496)
    ... 26 common frames omitted
```

Thanks

Comment: Disabling the hostname validation is nearly the same as disabling any kind of validation since all an attacker needs now is a certificate signed by a trusted CA, no matter what the subject is. This is usually easy to get. If you need to access some site with a non-matching certificate you should instead either use pinning to identify the site by the expected certificate or use a custom hostname verifier which checks for the hostname you expect.

Comment: Thanks, so how can I add a custom hostname verifier?

Comment: See https://tersesystems.com/2014/03/23/fixing-hostname-verification/ for example code.

Comment: I found that article too but it is for javax.net.ssl.SSLContext I'm using io.netty.handler.ssl.Sslcontext thats why I haven't been able to change the hostname verifier

Comment: Sorry, but then I cannot help further. I'm not really familiar with the various ways Java deals with SSL depending on a specific library (looks like too many different ways for the same thing) but I'm familiar with the security aspects of SSL.

Answer (score 6):

I found that adding  setAcceptAnyCertificate(true) to the clientConfig builder did the trick in this way:

```
sslContext = SslContextBuilder
    .forClient()
    .sslProvider(SslProvider.JDK)
    .trustManager(InsecureTrustManagerFactory.INSTANCE)
    .build();

DefaultAsyncHttpClientConfig.Builder builder = new DefaultAsyncHttpClientConfig.Builder();
builder.setSslContext(sslContext)
    .setAcceptAnyCertificate(true);

AsyncHttpClientConfig asyncHttpClientConfig = builder.build();
```

Thanks everyone

Answer (score 0):

This explains how you can import the certificate of the host you want to connect to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36483016/5296666

Comment: The certificate is being ignored, the problem is the hostname is different