# What is the equivalent of .setSSLHostnameVerifier(NoopHostnameVerifier.INSTANCE) in Netty world?

Tags: java, netty, reactor-netty

A small question regarding Netty and `io.netty.handler.ssl.SslContext`

In Tomcat and `org.apache.http.ssl.SSLContexts`, we have the possibility to perform the following:

HttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom()
.setSSLContext(SSLContexts.custom()
.loadKeyMaterial(*someKeystorePropertlyInitialized*)
.loadTrustMaterial(*someTruststorePropertlyInitialized*)
.build())
**.setSSLHostnameVerifier(NoopHostnameVerifier.INSTANCE)**
.build();

(Appreciate if we can leave the fonts and not wrap inside a code block)

This can for instance fix issues such as Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative DNS name matching xxx found
(This question is not about if `NoopHostnameVerifier.INSTANCE` is the proper way to fix this.)

My question is, what is the equivalent in Netty of `.setSSLHostnameVerifier(NoopHostnameVerifier.INSTANCE)`, **without** `.trustManager(InsecureTrustManagerFactory.INSTANCE)`, because I have a real trust store, I just want to skip the host name, not everything

Maybe something with `reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClient; HttpClient.create()` ?

Comment: This may help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41064432/disable-hostname-verification-in-io-netty-handler-ssl-sslcontext

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disable hostname verification in io.netty.handler.ssl.Sslcontext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41064432/disable-hostname-verification-in-io-netty-handler-ssl-sslcontext)

Comment: Hello @pyb, thank you for the links. I forgot to mention in my question, without habing to do InsecureTrustManagerFactory.INSTANCE, because I do not want to skip everything, just the host name. Good catch, question edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, Netty has hostname verification turned off by default -- see [this issue](https://github.com/netty/netty/issues/8537). It looks like the library you're using (reactor-netty) might have it turned on. There appears to be a [similar issue](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-netty/issues/752) on reactor-netty's github which points to the solution, but the code snippet provided seems to do more than what's necessary. Essentially, all you need is to access the `SSLEngine` from the `SslHandler` and make sure the endpoint identification algorithm is empty/null:

```java
HttpClient.create().secure(
        ssl -> ssl.sslContext(sslContext)
              .handlerConfigurator(handler-> {
                  SSLEngine engine = handler.engine();
                  SSLParameters params = new SSLParameters();
                  // ... set other SSL params
                  params.setEndpointIdentificationAlgorithm(null);
              })
);
```

Comment: CAn someone help me with `spring-webflux` I dont want to setup trust manager or other ssl stuff just want to enable `hostNameVerification` is there a property in spring or config changes when createing `WebClient`

Comment: I had to set params.setEndpointIdentificationAlgorithm("");