# java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative DNS name matching xxx found

Tags: ssl, dns, spring-webclient

I'm using Spring WebClient to invoke a webservice over SSL, but I'm getting **java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative DNS name matching lizzad.int.octa.com** found.

As far as I can see, this means that the certificate does not have the name lizzad.int.octa.com. This makes some sense because I've the service invokation working if I invoke another url.

But I was told to change the URL and it was assured that the certificate should be the same. Nevertheless it is not working and then the client asked me if I could bypass something in order to make this work in tests environment.

After researching a bit I found some code I thought it could be hepful to configure WebClient.

```
TcpClient tcpClient = TcpClient.create().secure(sslContextSpec -> {
            // configure ssl
            SslContextBuilder sslContextBuilder = SslContextBuilder.forClient();
                sslContextBuilder
                        .trustManager(InsecureTrustManagerFactory.INSTANCE);
            
            sslContextSpec.sslContext(sslContextBuilder)
                    .defaultConfiguration(SslProvider.DefaultConfigurationType.NONE)
                    .handshakeTimeoutMillis(30)
                    .closeNotifyFlushTimeoutMillis(12000)
                    .closeNotifyReadTimeoutMillis(12000)
                    .handlerConfigurator(
                            (handler)->{
                                SSLEngine engine = handler.engine();
                                engine.setNeedClientAuth(true);
                                SSLParameters params = new SSLParameters();
                                List<SNIMatcher> matchers = new LinkedList<>();
                                SNIMatcher matcher = new SNIMatcher(0) {

                                    @Override
                                    public boolean matches(SNIServerName serverName) {
                                        return true;
                                    }
                                };
                                matchers.add(matcher);
                                params.setSNIMatchers(matchers);
                                engine.setSSLParameters(params);
                            }
                    )
            ;
        });
        HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.from(tcpClient);

        return WebClient.builder()
                .defaultHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
                .defaultHeader(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT, MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE)
                .clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(httpClient)).build();
```

But it seams that Matcher is not what will make the hostname to be ignore.

On the other hand I also found here [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43371418/java-security-cert-certificateexception-no-subject-alternative-dns-name-matchin][1]

```
    new javax.net.ssl.HostnameVerifier() {

            public boolean verify(String hostname, javax.net.ssl.SSLSession sslSession) {
                    return true;
            }
        });
```

that if I was not using WebClient I could set a HostnameVerifier and return true in order to bypass the hostname verification.

Do you know if it is possible and how  can I define a HostnameVerifier like this in my WebClient Configuration to prevent
*java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative DNS name matching lizzad.int.octa.com*

Thanks
[1]: [java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative DNS name matching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43371418/java-security-cert-certificateexception-no-subject-alternative-dns-name-matchin)

Answer (score 0):

I think this cannot be configured/ignored from the client side. You are trying to call the server on `lizzad.int.octa.com` and it is actually reaching it however the server is saying that it won't continue to talk with the client because `lizzad.int.octa.com` is not present within the SAN field of the server certificate.

This stackoverflow question/answer is similar to yours: [Certificate for <localhost> doesn't match any of the subject alternative names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50928061/certificate-for-localhost-doesnt-match-any-of-the-subject-alternative-names/53822999#53822999)

I would advise to recreate the server certificate if it is possible. You just need to add `lizzad.int.octa.com` as a DNS for the san field. See below for an example with keytool:

```
keytool -genkeypair -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -alias server -dname "CN=server,OU=some-organisation-unit,O=some-organisation,C=US" -ext "SAN:c=DNS:lizzad.int.octa.com,IP:127.0.0.1" -validity 3650 -keystore identity.jks -storepass secret -keypass secret -deststoretype pkcs12
```

Comment: I had a clue that it was that the scenario, but the client insisted. Thanks a lot