# Error : java.security.cert.CertificateException: Illegal given domain name: abc_xyz.stg.myweb.com

Tags: java, ssl

Hi team i found below exception when calling an api

> https://abc_xyz.stg.myweb.com/api/AuthorizedUser?username=admin&password=admin
>
> java.security.cert.CertificateException: Illegal given domain name

when getting response from server using Jersey.
Everything is fine when i get response from postman.

Why it is illegal domain name, whether browser not refuse to open this.

If my domain name not contains underscore then this exception is not rising.
Is this problem of underscore in domain name?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix the "java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative names present" error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19540289/how-to-fix-the-java-security-cert-certificateexception-no-subject-alternative)

Comment: No it is different question, In this scenario it is not connected with endpoint

Comment: SSL was issued for IP/domain/subdomain?

Comment: @Altmish-E-Azam Hi can u brief this what you saying

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In case anyone see this issue again. This issue is caused by an old jdk that thinks an underscore is invalid as the sub domain name, which in a later version has been removed from the jdk. So in short upgrade jdk version will solve this issue.

Comment: what version of JDK you were using before? and what version did you update too?

Comment: thanks @jacob, it is resolve my issue when i see docs, it said java 1.8.25 above version resolve this issue.

Comment: Very strange.  Here I am, years later, using JDK 16, and I'm having this problem.  I had to register and refer to the alternate name with '-'s instead of '_'s.

Comment: Guys you saved my live...this issue is crazy....

Answer (score 7):

In case someone see this issue again and don't want to change jdk version, it is possible to disable the SSL Host name verification (and it is not the good solution but sometimes it is not possible to avoid this..) :

```
    HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
        public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Comment: +1 but it could be insecure way. ref: [How to resolve Insecure HostnameVerifier](https://support.google.com/faqs/answer/7188426?hl=en)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and couldn't update jdk nor wanted disable ssl host name verification. Changing the underscore character in the name to a dash ('-' instead of '_') worked perfectly. Apparently dash and underscore are evaluated the same.

Comment: That's not true

Comment: I just ran into this same issue.  I can confirm that simply replacing '_'s with '-'s in my URL did NOT work.  I had to actually register the alternate DNS name to get things working.