# From where does the "Contains non-LDH ASCII characters" exception come from?

Tags: java, exception

I develop an application (spring-magnolia) that around this new year (2018) started to throw for me this exception but not for any other colleagues.

The exception is right, there is an `_` in the a configured host name, so that domain name should be fixed. Still, it was working before and for the other folks it is still working, not throwing this exception. I tried many different things, from tomcat settings to using an older JRE (1.7)... and even switched from Ubuntu to Windows but the exception wasn't left behind.

One of my mates is working with me in the office, using Mac, and I could look up his settings to catch what is making this difference, but don't really know what else should I look up as the tools, environment are the same (maven, same code, tried different jdks).

Could someone give me a clue what triggered the exception for me but not for others and if I could set it somewhere to ignore this exception?

```
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: Illegal given domain name: xyz_t-bud.rd-services.com
    at sun.security.util.HostnameChecker.matchDNS(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.util.HostnameChecker.match(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkIdentity(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkIdentity(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(Unknown Source)
    ... 135 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Contains non-LDH ASCII characters
    at java.net.IDN.toASCIIInternal(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.IDN.toASCII(Unknown Source)
    at javax.net.ssl.SNIHostName.<init>(Unknown Source)
    ... 141 more
```

Comment: Check out this. https://stackoverflow.com/a/48444910/2465608 Please try upgrade to JDK8 and see if resolves.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'm using the latest 8 161 version I tried to revert to some older 8 version and even to 7, but still got this exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently I wasn't testing with older JDKs, as eclipse wasn't picking it up. After uninstalling the latest JDK `1.8.0_161`and installing the JDK that my colleague is having, that is `1.8.0_111` I am no longer getting this error... I did try this JDK before, but I didn't uninstall the latest JDK and so the project was in fact still using the latest JDK...