# How to make feign disable-ssl-validation property work on spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, ssl-certificate, spring-cloud-feign

I'm developing a microservice with Spring Boot and Feign for external services access.
I have to access an external service in a test/development environment. This environment has another instance that is hosted at a different location. The problem is that this test URL hasn't a valid SSL certificate, and the feign configuration seems to fail.

I tried adding the application.yml file:

```
feign:
  httpclient:
    disable-ssl-validation: true
```

but I still get the same Exception:

```
feign.RetryableException: No subject alternative names matching IP address someIp found executing POST https://someIp:someport/somePath
```

And after further investigation, I've found that it was caused by a `java.security.cert.CertificateException`

Shouldn't this application.yml configuration disable the SSL certificate validation and, therefore, avoid this exception?

Comment: Question is not clear. Can you please elaborate and ask specific question?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19540289/how-to-fix-the-java-security-cert-certificateexception-no-subject-alternative

Comment: Are you using EUREKA and Ribbon or any other service registry or load balance?

Comment: @LeonardoMeinerzRamos Application which is secured with SSL (or TLS for that matter) cannot be accessed via HTTP. So if you dissable ssl validation then you wont cannot call HTTPS (as the error msg you shared). But you can call ie. HTTP to HTTP. For the target server should dissable SSL. Hope I am clear.

Comment: @CodeRider I'm not using any service registry or load balancer yet.

Comment: @CodeRider If I understood your last comment, your suggestion is to disable SSL on the target server and use HTTP instead. Is this correct? If it is, I'm afraid that is not possible. The production environment's SSL certificate IS VALID, the problem is the test environment that only has a copy of the production certificate, which is invalid.

Comment: Ok, I've added a Feign Configuration class to the client to disable SSL by code and it worked out, but I still would like to know why this YML configuration does not work

Comment: @LeonardoMeinerzRamos I hope i have answered it in your way. Please mark my solution as answer if you understood the scenario here.

Comment: @LeonardoMeinerzRamos, can you share your code Feign Configuration class? I am facing this same problem.

Answer (score -1):

As discussed in comments, we should not call secured (HTTPS) services in a unsecured way (HTTP). Not only does it **violate the same origin policy**, but since the service you are calling from is insecure it has the **potential to be interfered with and leak** all the data you are trying to keep secure.
Use HTTPS for the entire process.

Get the certificates installed in calling and target machines.
This would cover your entire testing cycle.

Comment: This is correct, but it does not answer the question: "Shouldn't this application.yml configuration disable the SSL certificate validation and, therefore, avoid this exception?"

Comment: You can call the target server if it is also running on http. You need to disable ssl in your targer server and restart it. Then you code should work. Because your non ssl request is looking for ssl request you got that error