# kafka - ssl handshake failing

Tags: ssl, apache-kafka, confluent-platform

i've setup SSL on my local Kafka instance, and when i start the Kafka console producer/consumer on SSL port, it is giving SSL Handshake error

```
Karans-MacBook-Pro:keystore karanalang$ $CONFLUENT_HOME/bin/kafka-console-producer --broker-list localhost:9093 --topic karantest --producer.config $CONFLUENT_HOME/props/client-ssl.properties
>[2021-11-10 13:15:09,824] ERROR [Producer clientId=console-producer] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9093) failed authentication due to: SSL handshake failed (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2021-11-10 13:15:09,826] WARN [Producer clientId=console-producer] Bootstrap broker localhost:9093 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2021-11-10 13:15:10,018] ERROR [Producer clientId=console-producer] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9093) failed authentication due to: SSL handshake failed (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2021-11-10 13:15:10,019] WARN [Producer clientId=console-producer] Bootstrap broker localhost:9093 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2021-11-10 13:15:10,195] ERROR [Producer clientId=console-producer] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9093) failed authentication due to: SSL handshake failed (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
```

Here are the changes made :

1. create the truststore & keystore

Here is output of the openssl command to check the SSL connectivity :

```
Karans-MacBook-Pro:keystore karanalang$ openssl s_client -debug -connect localhost:9093 -tls1
CONNECTED(00000005)
write to 0x13d7bdf90 [0x13e01ea03] (118 bytes => 118 (0x76))
0000 - 16 03 01 00 71 01 00 00-6d 03 01 81 e8 00 cd c4   ....q...m.......
0010 - 04 4b 64 86 3e 30 97 32-c3 66 3a 8c ed 05 bf 97   .Kd.>0.2.f:.....
0020 - ff d5 b2 a4 26 fe 99 c0-7f 94 a1 00 00 2e c0 14   ....&...........
0030 - c0 0a 00 39 ff 85 00 88-00 81 00 35 00 84 c0 13   ...9.......5....
---
0076 - <SPACES/NULS>
read from 0x13d7bdf90 [0x13e01a803] (5 bytes => 5 (0x5))
0005 - <SPACES/NULS>
4307385836:error:1400410B:SSL routines:CONNECT_CR_SRVR_HELLO:wrong version number:/System/Volumes/Data/SWE/macOS/BuildRoots/e90674e518/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/libressl/libressl-56.60.2/libressl-2.8/ssl/ssl_pkt.c:386:
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 5 bytes and written 0 bytes
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1
    Cipher    : 0000
    Session-ID: 
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: 
    Start Time: 1636579015
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
```

Here is the server.properties :

```
# Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
# contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
# this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
# The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
# (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
# the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.

# see kafka.server.KafkaConfig for additional details and defaults

############################# Server Basics #############################

# The id of the broker. This must be set to a unique integer for each broker.
broker.id=0

############################# Socket Server Settings #############################

# The address the socket server listens on. It will get the value returned from 
# java.net.InetAddress.getCanonicalHostName() if not configured.
#   FORMAT:
#     listeners = listener_name://host_name:port
#   EXAMPLE:
#     listeners = PLAINTEXT://your.host.name:9092
# SSL CHANGE
listeners=PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092,SSL://localhost:9093

# Hostname and port the broker will advertise to producers and consumers. If not set, 
# it uses the value for "listeners" if configured.  Otherwise, it will use the value
# returned from java.net.InetAddress.getCanonicalHostName().
# SSL CHANGE
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092,SSL://localhost:9093
ssl.client.auth=none

# Maps listener names to security protocols, the default is for them to be the same. See the config documentation for more details
listener.security.protocol.map=PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,SSL:SSL,SASL_PLAINTEXT:SASL_PLAINTEXT,SASL_SSL:SASL_SSL

# The number of threads that the server uses for receiving requests from the network and sending responses to the network
num.network.threads=3

# The number of threads that the server uses for processing requests, which may include disk I/O
num.io.threads=8

# The send buffer (SO_SNDBUF) used by the socket server
socket.send.buffer.bytes=102400

# The receive buffer (SO_RCVBUF) used by the socket server
socket.receive.buffer.bytes=102400

# The maximum size of a request that the socket server will accept (protection against OOM)
socket.request.max.bytes=104857600


############################# Log Basics #############################

# A comma separated list of directories under which to store log files
log.dirs=/tmp/kafka-logs

# The default number of log partitions per topic. More partitions allow greater
# parallelism for consumption, but this will also result in more files across
# the brokers.
num.partitions=1

# The number of threads per data directory to be used for log recovery at startup and flushing at shutdown.
# This value is recommended to be increased for installations with data dirs located in RAID array.
num.recovery.threads.per.data.dir=1

############################# Internal Topic Settings  #############################
# The replication factor for the group metadata internal topics "__consumer_offsets" and "__transaction_state"
# For anything other than development testing, a value greater than 1 is recommended to ensure availability such as 3.
offsets.topic.replication.factor=1
transaction.state.log.replication.factor=1
transaction.state.log.min.isr=1

############################# Log Flush Policy #############################

# Messages are immediately written to the filesystem but by default we only fsync() to sync
# the OS cache lazily. The following configurations control the flush of data to disk.
# There are a few important trade-offs here:
#    1. Durability: Unflushed data may be lost if you are not using replication.
#    2. Latency: Very large flush intervals may lead to latency spikes when the flush does occur as there will be a lot of data to flush.
#    3. Throughput: The flush is generally the most expensive operation, and a small flush interval may lead to excessive seeks.
# The settings below allow one to configure the flush policy to flush data after a period of time or
# every N messages (or both). This can be done globally and overridden on a per-topic basis.

# The number of messages to accept before forcing a flush of data to disk
#log.flush.interval.messages=10000

# The maximum amount of time a message can sit in a log before we force a flush
#log.flush.interval.ms=1000

############################# Log Retention Policy #############################

# The following configurations control the disposal of log segments. The policy can
# be set to delete segments after a period of time, or after a given size has accumulated.
# A segment will be deleted whenever *either* of these criteria are met. Deletion always happens
# from the end of the log.

# The minimum age of a log file to be eligible for deletion due to age
log.retention.hours=168

# A size-based retention policy for logs. Segments are pruned from the log unless the remaining
# segments drop below log.retention.bytes. Functions independently of log.retention.hours.
#log.retention.bytes=1073741824

# The maximum size of a log segment file. When this size is reached a new log segment will be created.
log.segment.bytes=1073741824

# The interval at which log segments are checked to see if they can be deleted according
# to the retention policies
log.retention.check.interval.ms=300000

############################# Zookeeper #############################

# Zookeeper connection string (see zookeeper docs for details).
# This is a comma separated host:port pairs, each corresponding to a zk
# server. e.g. "127.0.0.1:3000,127.0.0.1:3001,127.0.0.1:3002".
# You can also append an optional chroot string to the urls to specify the
# root directory for all kafka znodes.
zookeeper.connect=localhost:2181

# Timeout in ms for connecting to zookeeper
zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms=18000

##################### Confluent Metrics Reporter #######################
# Confluent Control Center and Confluent Auto Data Balancer integration
#
# Uncomment the following lines to publish monitoring data for
# Confluent Control Center and Confluent Auto Data Balancer
# If you are using a dedicated metrics cluster, also adjust the settings
# to point to your metrics kakfa cluster.
#metric.reporters=io.confluent.metrics.reporter.ConfluentMetricsReporter
#confluent.metrics.reporter.bootstrap.servers=localhost:9092
#
# Uncomment the following line if the metrics cluster has a single broker
#confluent.metrics.reporter.topic.replicas=1

############################# Group Coordinator Settings #############################

# The following configuration specifies the time, in milliseconds, that the GroupCoordinator will delay the initial consumer rebalance.
# The rebalance will be further delayed by the value of group.initial.rebalance.delay.ms as new members join the group, up to a maximum of max.poll.interval.ms.
# The default value for this is 3 seconds.
# We override this to 0 here as it makes for a better out-of-the-box experience for development and testing.
# However, in production environments the default value of 3 seconds is more suitable as this will help to avoid unnecessary, and potentially expensive, rebalances during application startup.
group.initial.rebalance.delay.ms=0


############################# Confluent Authorizer Settings  #############################

# Uncomment to enable Confluent Authorizer with support for ACLs, LDAP groups and RBAC
#authorizer.class.name=io.confluent.kafka.security.authorizer.ConfluentServerAuthorizer
# Semi-colon separated list of super users in the format <principalType>:<principalName>
#super.users=
# Specify a valid Confluent license. By default free-tier license will be used
#confluent.license=
# Replication factor for the topic used for licensing. Default is 3.
confluent.license.topic.replication.factor=1

# Uncomment the following lines and specify values where required to enable CONFLUENT provider for RBAC and centralized ACLs
# Enable CONFLUENT provider 
#confluent.authorizer.access.rule.providers=ZK_ACL,CONFLUENT
# Bootstrap servers for RBAC metadata. Must be provided if this broker is not in the metadata cluster
#confluent.metadata.bootstrap.servers=PLAINTEXT://127.0.0.1:9092
# Replication factor for the metadata topic used for authorization. Default is 3.
confluent.metadata.topic.replication.factor=1

# Replication factor for the topic used for audit logs. Default is 3.
confluent.security.event.logger.exporter.kafka.topic.replicas=1

# Listeners for metadata server
#confluent.metadata.server.listeners=http://0.0.0.0:8090
# Advertised listeners for metadata server
#confluent.metadata.server.advertised.listeners=http://127.0.0.1:8090

############################# Confluent Data Balancer Settings  #############################

# The Confluent Data Balancer is used to measure the load across the Kafka cluster and move data
# around as necessary. Comment out this line to disable the Data Balancer.
confluent.balancer.enable=true

# By default, the Data Balancer will only move data when an empty broker (one with no partitions on it)
# is added to the cluster or a broker failure is detected. Comment out this line to allow the Data
# Balancer to balance load across the cluster whenever an imbalance is detected.
#confluent.balancer.heal.uneven.load.trigger=ANY_UNEVEN_LOAD

# The default time to declare a broker permanently failed is 1 hour (3600000 ms).
# Uncomment this line to turn off broker failure detection, or adjust the threshold
# to change the duration before a broker is declared failed.
#confluent.balancer.heal.broker.failure.threshold.ms=-1

# Edit and uncomment the following line to limit the network bandwidth used by data balancing operations.
# This value is in bytes/sec/broker. The default is 10MB/sec.
#confluent.balancer.throttle.bytes.per.second=10485760

# Capacity Limits -- when set to positive values, the Data Balancer will attempt to keep
# resource usage per-broker below these limits.
# Edit and uncomment this line to limit the maximum number of replicas per broker. Default is unlimited.
#confluent.balancer.max.replicas=10000

# Edit and uncomment this line to limit what fraction of the log disk (0-1.0) is used before rebalancing.
# The default (below) is 85% of the log disk.
#confluent.balancer.disk.max.load=0.85

# Edit and uncomment these lines to define a maximum network capacity per broker, in bytes per
# second. The Data Balancer will attempt to ensure that brokers are using less than this amount
# of network bandwidth when rebalancing.
# Here, 10MB/s. The default is unlimited capacity.
#confluent.balancer.network.in.max.bytes.per.second=10485760
#confluent.balancer.network.out.max.bytes.per.second=10485760

# Edit and uncomment this line to identify specific topics that should not be moved by the data balancer.
# Removal operations always move topics regardless of this setting.
#confluent.balancer.exclude.topic.names=

# Edit and uncomment this line to identify topic prefixes that should not be moved by the data balancer.
# (For example, a "confluent.balancer" prefix will match all of "confluent.balancer.a", "confluent.balancer.b",
# "confluent.balancer.c", and so on.)
# Removal operations always move topics regardless of this setting.
#confluent.balancer.exclude.topic.prefixes=

# The replication factor for the topics the Data Balancer uses to store internal state.
# For anything other than development testing, a value greater than 1 is recommended to ensure availability.
# The default value is 3.
confluent.balancer.topic.replication.factor=1

################################## Confluent Telemetry Settings  ##################################

# To start using Telemetry, first generate a Confluent Cloud API key/secret. This can be done with
# instructions at https://docs.confluent.io/current/cloud/using/api-keys.html. Note that you should
# be using the '--resource cloud' flag.
#
# After generating an API key/secret, to enable Telemetry uncomment the lines below and paste
# in your API key/secret.
#
#confluent.telemetry.enabled=true
#confluent.telemetry.api.key=<CLOUD_API_KEY>
#confluent.telemetry.api.secret=<CCLOUD_API_SECRET>

############ SSL #################

ssl.truststore.location=/Users/karanalang/Documents/Technology/confluent-6.2.1/ssl_certs/truststore/kafka.truststore.jks
ssl.truststore.password=test123
ssl.keystore.location=/Users/karanalang/Documents/Technology/confluent-6.2.1/ssl_certs/keystore/kafka.keystore.jks
ssl.keystore.password=test123
ssl.key.password=test123

# confluent.metrics.reporter.bootstrap.servers=localhost:9093
# confluent.metrics.reporter.security.protocol=SSL
# confluent.metrics.reporter.ssl.truststore.location=/Users/karanalang/Documents/Technology/confluent-6.2.1/ssl_certs/truststore/kafka.truststore.jks
# confluent.metrics.reporter.ssl.truststore.password=test123
# confluent.metrics.reporter.ssl.keystore.location=/Users/karanalang/Documents/Technology/confluent-6.2.1/ssl_certs/keystore/kafka.keystore.jks
# confluent.metrics.reporter.ssl.keystore.password=test123
# confluent.metrics.reporter.ssl.key.password=test123
```

client-ssl.properties:

```
bootstrap.servers=localhost:9093
security.protocol=SSL
ssl.truststore.location=/Users/karanalang/Documents/Technology/confluent-6.2.1/ssl_certs/truststore/kafka.truststore.jks
ssl.truststore.password=test123
ssl.keystore.location=/Users/karanalang/Documents/Technology/confluent-6.2.1/ssl_certs/keystore/kafka.keystore.jks
ssl.keystore.password=test123
ssl.key.password=test123
```

Commands to start the Console Producer/Consumer :

```
$CONFLUENT_HOME/bin/kafka-console-producer --broker-list localhost:9093 --topic karantest --producer.config $CONFLUENT_HOME/props/client-ssl.properties
$CONFLUENT_HOME/bin/kafka-console-consumer --bootstrap-server localhost:9093 --topic karantest --consumer.config $CONFLUENT_HOME/props/client-ssl.properties --from-beginning
```

Any ideas on how to resolve this ?

Update :
This is the error when i try to debug (using - export KAFKA_OPTS=-Djavax.net.debug=all)

```
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|0E|kafka-producer-network-thread | console-producer|2021-11-10 14:04:26.107 PST|SSLExtensions.java:173|Ignore unavailable extension: status_request
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|0E|kafka-producer-network-thread | console-producer|2021-11-10 14:04:26.107 PST|SSLExtensions.java:173|Ignore unavailable extension: status_request
javax.net.ssl|ERROR|0E|kafka-producer-network-thread | console-producer|2021-11-10 14:04:26.108 PST|TransportContext.java:341|Fatal (CERTIFICATE_UNKNOWN): No name matching localhost found (
"throwable" : {
  java.security.cert.CertificateException: No name matching localhost found
    at java.base/sun.security.util.HostnameChecker.matchDNS(HostnameChecker.java:234)
    at java.base/sun.security.util.HostnameChecker.match(HostnameChecker.java:103)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkIdentity(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:455)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkIdentity(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:429)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:283)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:141)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:1335)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.onConsumeCertificate(CertificateMessage.java:1232)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.consume(CertificateMessage.java:1175)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(SSLHandshake.java:392)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:443)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl$DelegatedTask$DelegatedAction.run(SSLEngineImpl.java:1074)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl$DelegatedTask$DelegatedAction.run(SSLEngineImpl.java:1061)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl$DelegatedTask.run(SSLEngineImpl.java:1008)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SslTransportLayer.runDelegatedTasks(SslTransportLayer.java:509)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SslTransportLayer.handshakeUnwrap(SslTransportLayer.java:601)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SslTransportLayer.doHandshake(SslTransportLayer.java:447)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SslTransportLayer.handshake(SslTransportLayer.java:332)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.prepare(KafkaChannel.java:229)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.pollSelectionKeys(Selector.java:563)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.poll(Selector.java:499)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.poll(NetworkClient.java:639)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.runOnce(Sender.java:327)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run(Sender.java:242)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding the following in `client-ssl.properties` resolved the issue:

```
ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm=
```

This setting means the certificate does not match the hostname of the machine you are using to run the consumer. That seems to be recommended approach in this case.

Related thread:
[Kafka java consumer SSL handshake Error : java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative names present](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60895431/kafka-java-consumer-ssl-handshake-error-java-security-cert-certificateexceptio)

Answer (score 1):

Try to set identification algorithm for for producer and consumer also.

```
ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm=
producer.ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm=
consumer.ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm=
```

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have connection or problems.

You can test access with:
*openssl s_client -debug -connect servername:port -tls1_2*

Answer must be: "Verify return code: 0 (ok)

In other case you have no access.