# hostname verification in weblogic

Tags: java, ssl, certificate, weblogic, hostname

I am getting following error when tried to run my web services client in Weblogic Server, tried various options suggested in various sites

Certificate chain received from aa.aa.abc.com - 123.158.127.108 failed hostname verification check. Certificate contained abc.com but check expected aa.aa.abc.com

1. One option is to suppress the hostname verification by using following option,
   which is not preferred option.

   -Dweblogic.security.SSL.ignoreHostnameVerification=true
2. Tried setting Custom Hostname verifier through weblogic Console    "weblogic.security.utils.SSLWLSWildcardHostnameVerifier", still getting same error
3. Tried registering my Custom Hostname verifier through code by writing dummy HostName verifier

   ```
    requestCtx.put("com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.https.client.hostname.verifier", new HostnameVerifier() {

                                   @Override
                                   public boolean verify(String hostname,
                                           SSLSession session) {
                                       return true;
                                   }
                               });
   ```

   above code did not help  because weblogic seem to be using its own Http handler instead of SUN J2SE implementation, some even suggested to use  "-DUseSunHttpHandler=true".

I want to know is there any better way to do programmatically/dynamically so that it will not have any impact on other applications ?

Comment: This indicates that the server is set up wrong. Fix the problem at the server side and don't try to weaken TLS by trying to work around a broken server setup.

Comment: Another idea is to add a subject alternate name to your certs so that multiple hostnames will succeed: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8744607/how-to-add-subject-alernative-name-to-ssl-certs We do this so both the IP address, short host name, and fully qualified hostname are all accepted. No code changes or java params needed

Answer (score 0):

I remember also getting same error. Got thu it with below code snippet Try this.

```
     url = new URL(urlStr);

     HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection)url.openConnection();

            conn.setHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier()  
            {        
                public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session)  
                {  
                    return true;  
                }  
            });
```

Comment: Which in effect accepts any certificate signed by a trusted CA and thus makes you wide open for man-in-the-middle attacks.

Comment: we are not directly dealing with HttpsURLConnection , we use jaxws to send SOAP message.