# How to create CSR with SANs using keytool

Tags: certificate, keytool

I'd like to ask whether it is possible to create CSR that contains SAN records.

I created keystore as

```
keytool -genkeypair -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -alias testAlias -ext SAN=dns:test.example.com -keystore test.jks -storetype JKS -dname "CN=test"
```

I can check using keytool, that SAN is in keystore

```
keytool -list -v -keystore test.jks
```

and relevnt part of the output is

```
#1: ObjectId: 2.5.29.17 Criticality=false
SubjectAlternativeName [
  DNSName: test.example.com
]
```

Then I created CSR using keytool:

```
keytool -certreq -file test.csr -keystore test.jks -alias testAlias
```

but in CSR there is information about SAN missing.

How to check:

```
keytool -printcertreq -file test.csr -v
```

correctly there should be something similar to

```
Extension Request:

#1: ObjectId: 2.5.29.17 Criticality=false
SubjectAlternativeName [
  DNSName: test.example.com
]
```

Did I miss some option for `certreq` ?

Answer (score 35):

when You generate CSR you need to specify **-ext** attribute again

```
keytool -certreq -file test.csr -keystore test.jks -alias testAlias -ext SAN=dns:test.example.com
```

Comment: using multiple DNS and even IP is also possible e.g: -ext "san=dns:test.example.com,dns:test.example.net,dns:test2.example.com,ip:XX.XXX.XX.XXX"  Creating CSR file had worked for me... just need to get my certificate to make sure things are working

Comment: Also note, the response to the CSR can overwrite stuff for you, too, so that the CSR signer can put SANs in there, and manage other attributes of the certificate.