# How to make Restlet client ignore SSL Certificate problems

Tags: java, ssl, https, restlet

I am currently working in a test environment where the server has a default Self signed SSL certificate. I am using Restlet 2.1-RC2 and instantiating client resource like this:

```
Client client = new Client(new Context(), Protocol.HTTP);
cr = new ClientResource(String.format(itql_endpoint,riQuery));
cr.setNext(client);
```

and reusing client for each call I make. How can I set up client so that it ignores problematic certificates.

Comment: No - I am particularly asking about how to do this with the Restlet framework (http://www.restlet.org/) .I have done this on other occasions with other types of connections, I would just like to know the right way of doing it with Restlet

Comment: Apologies, somehow I did not get that...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**The right way** is to import this self-signed certificate into the client's trust store, using `keytool` for example:

```
keytool -import -file server-cert.pem -alias myserver -keystore mytruststore.jks
```

You can either do it directly in the JRE's trust store (`lib/security/cacerts`), which may lack some flexibility, or do it in your own copy of this file, which you then set as the trust store (the default password is `changeit` or `changeme` on OSX). You configure this truststore globally for your application using the usual `javax.net.ssl.trustStore*` system properties (e.g. `-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=mytruststore` system property (and `-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword`) or you can configure it for a specific connector in Restlet using the server context parameters, for example:

```
Series<Parameter> parameters = client.getContext().getParameters();
parameters.add("truststorePath", "/path/to/your/truststore.jks");
// parameters.add("truststorePassword", "password");
// parameters.add("trustPassword", "password");
// parameters.add("truststoreType", "JKS");
```

**The wrong way** is to use a `TrustManager` that's going to disable any verification and pass it via an [`SslContextFactory`](http://www.restlet.org/documentation/2.1/jse/ext/org/restlet/ext/ssl/SslContextFactory.html) (in the SSL extension). Something along these lines.

```
TrustManager tm = new X509TrustManager() {
    public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain,
                    String authType)
                    throws CertificateException {
    }

    public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
        return new X509Certificate[0];
    }

    public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain,
                    String authType)
                    throws CertificateException {
        // This will never throw an exception.
        // This doesn't check anything at all: it's insecure.
    }
};

final SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
sslContext.init(null, new TrustManager[] {tm}, null);
Context context = client.getContext();
context.getAttributes().put("sslContextFactory", new SslContextFactory() {
    public void init(Series<Parameter> parameters) { }
    public SSLContext createSslContext() { return sslContext; }
});
```

While the first method may seem a bit more tedious than the second (since you need to obtain the server certificate first and copy files around), the second will simply make the error messages go away by not verifying anything about the server certificate, thereby making it vulnerable to active MITM attacks. This will apply to any connection where this `SSLContext` is configured. (This "wrong way isn't wrong because it uses a custom `SSLContext`, it's wrong because of this particular configuration of the `SSLContext`.)

Comment: Thanks a lot. A very complete answer! Unfortunately now stuck with javax.net.ssl.SSLException: hostname in certificate didn't match. And there seems no way around that: http://restlet.tigris.org/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=1078

Comment: I must admit I can't remember off the top of my head how to tweak the host name verification. The best way is to use a self-signed certificate with the correct name. Often, setting just the CN in the Subject DN should do, but you can also set the Subject Alt Name (you'll need it if using an IP address anyway), see http://stackoverflow.com/a/8444863/372643

Comment: I used a self signed certificate in Android, this solution in combination with http://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl.html#SelfSigned fixed my problem. Thank you so much!

Comment: Hi @Bruno, maybe you can share some idea with this Restlet issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66794041/using-xstream-extension-with-swagger-instead-of-jackson

Answer (score 1):

```
// Create all-trusting host name verifier
HostnameVerifier allHostsValid = new HostnameVerifier() {
      public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
        return true;
      }
    };
HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(allHostsValid);
```