# Create a Java Keystore from a openssl Self-Signed certificate file

Tags: java, ssl, openssl

I am beginner in `Cryptography` concept. I want connect to a server that use `SSL` for its security by `OpenSSL`. It give to me its certificate file in `PEM` format. I want use its certificate file in java. I think must convert server certificate file to `Java TrustStore`.

Do I think?
Do you can a suggestion for me?

(Sorry if I am using the wrong terminology or grammar, I am learning english language.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to import it directly. See the [documentation for the `keytool` utility](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/keytool.html).

Comment: I am confused. I must create a keystore with its private key and import server certificate to it?

Comment: @MJM, no you just create a keystore (which you'll use as a truststore) by importing this certificate into it (using `-import`, same command as [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9003614/372643), without the Restlet-specific config and without using the "wrong way").