# SSLSocket and AES Encryption

Tags: ssl, aes

We need to use AES encryption for client server communication, so when I enable the Cipher Suite TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA on a SSLServetSocket ( using Java 6) and run the program, i am getting below exception

**No available certificate or key corresponds to the SSL cipher suites which are enabled**

My question is can we AES encryption over SSLSocket or it needs to be a regular socket. If we can't use it, can anyone please provide me an  example of client server communication using AES encryption.

Here is the code

```
public class AESServerSocketTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SSLServerSocket serverSocket;
        try 
        {
            SSLContext ctx = javax.net.ssl.SSLContext.getDefault();
            serverSocket =(SSLServerSocket)ctx.getServerSocketFactory().createServerSocket(8181);
            serverSocket.setEnabledCipherSuites(new String[]{"TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA"});        

            SSLSocket in = (SSLSocket)serverSocket.accept(); 
        }
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            System.out.println("Exception " + e);
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: How did you configure your certificate/keystore? Does it work at least without setting any specific cipher suites?

Comment: It works when I set it to anonymous cipher suite. I haven't added any certificate/key to the keystore, as AES uses symmetric key for encryption and decryption, do we need add to it? If yes how do we share it with clients.

Answer (score 1):

The anonymous cipher suites don't perform any authentication. Even with encryption, you're talking over an encrypted channel to a remote party, but you can't be sure who that is, so it could be a man in the middle (MITM). The [TLS 1.1 specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4346#appendix-A.5) says the following about anonymous cipher suites:

> The following cipher suites are used for completely anonymous
> Diffie-Hellman communications in which neither party is authenticated.
> Note that this mode is vulnerable to man-in-the-middle attacks and is
> therefore deprecated.

In short, don't use them (except for testing perhaps), or if you're really sure that there won't be an active MITM. (The TLS 1.2 specification is even more strongly worded against their usage.)

If you want to use TLS securely, you'll need a way for the client to verify the identity's remote party. In the vast majority of cases, this is done using an X.509 certificate. In particular, for the `TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA` cipher suite, you'll need requires a certificate with an RSA public key (which explains the error message you get).

You should generate or request a certificate (self-signed or via a CA, perhaps your own, depending on how the clients can be configured) that identifies correctly the server. Not only the certificate will need to be trusted by the client (either explicitly or via an established CA), but its identity information will need to match the server's, under the name the client is trying to connect to it.

From your example, it's not clear whether you're implementing HTTPS (for example) or your own protocol over SSL/TLS. [RFC 6125](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6125) is the latest specification in this area, which unifies practices around multiple protocols (e.g. HTTPS, LDAPS, IMAPS, ...). Since it's quite a recent RFC, few libraries explicitly implement it (although they may do in practice, since it consolidates best practices). In doubt, it's usually sensible to adhere to the [RFC 2818, section 3.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2818#section-3.1) (HTTP over TLS) guidelines on this subject:

> If a subjectAltName extension of type dNSName is present, that MUST
> be used as the identity. Otherwise, the (most specific) Common Name
> field in the Subject field of the certificate MUST be used. Although
> the use of the Common Name is existing practice, it is deprecated and
> Certification Authorities are encouraged to use the dNSName instead.
>
> Matching is performed using the matching rules specified by
> [RFC2459].  If more than one identity of a given type is present in
> the certificate (e.g., more than one dNSName name, a match in any one
> of the set is considered acceptable.) Names may contain the wildcard
> character * which is considered to match any single domain name
> component or component fragment. E.g., *.a.com matches foo.a.com but
> not bar.foo.a.com. f*.com matches foo.com but not bar.com.
>
> In some cases, the URI is specified as an IP address rather than a
> hostname. In this case, the iPAddress subjectAltName must be present
> in the certificate and must exactly match the IP in the URI.

([RFC 6125 explicitly discourages the use of wildcard certificates](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6125#section-7.2).)

For practical reasons, IP addresses in certificates are not ideal (I don't think many commercial CAs would generate such certificates anyway). If you can, use the Subject Alternative Name extension, failing that, putting the host name in the `CN=` RDN of your Subject DN should be sufficient. There are notes on how to generate a CSR/certificate with a SAN in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8444863/372643). In particular, it's possible using the [`-ext` option of Java 7's `keytool`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/keytool.html) (e.g. `-ext san=dns:www.example.com`); note that the keystore generated by Java 7's keytool should be usable on previous versions of the JRE too.

In addition, if you don't have any other code than `SSLContext.getDefault()` (you could also use the default `SSLServerSocketFactory` in this case), you'll need to specify the keystore: the JRE doesn't have a default value for this (as opposed to the trust store). This can be done using the `javax.net.ssl.keyStore` (and related system properties). There is more on this topic in this answer (for example): https://stackoverflow.com/a/6341566/372643

Comment: Thanks for your reply. we will be implementing our own protocol ( not https), can we generate a public key for AES, I thought it uses only one key for encryption and decryption. what is the procedure to use AES encryption for Client Server communication.

Comment: TLS negotiates shared/symmetric keys on the fly during the TLS handshake, which are then used for encryption during the rest of the communication. You wouldn't normally need to get access to them yourself at all. The public/private keys are used in the certificates (only used during the handshake itself) for authenticating the remote party and for negotiating these short-lived shared keys. You might be able to use Pre-Shared Keys (PSK) instead, but that's probably harder to set up if you're not familiar with "traditional" SSL/TLS. (Note that what I said in my answer was not specific to HTTPS.)

Answer (score 0):

> No available certificate or key corresponds to the SSL cipher suites
>   which are enabled

This error means:

Either that that the private keys/certificates are not suitable/accepted by the cipher suites you have enabled ( This can most likely mean e.g. short key length) or that you have not configured any certificates.