# Connecting to servlet https URL

Tags: java, spring, ssl, https, httpclient

I want to access a secure URL using HttpsURLConnection and am having trouble reading the content back.

I am using the trustmanager example given [here](http://humandoing.net/blog/2006/03/06/java-ssl-trust-manager/) and have added the following code to access the page content:

```
HttpsURLConnection urlc = (HttpsURLConnection) new URL( <url> ).openConnection();
BufferedReader readIn= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlc.getInputStream()));
String eachLine;
String inputLine = "";
while ((eachLine = readIn.readLine()) != null) {
   inputLine += eachLine;
}
```

The trouble is, I keep getting the error:

```
java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative names present
```

Any ideas why?
Thanks

**EDIT**
I forgot to mention, I am doing this using Spring and trying to call a servlet from another class.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10258101/sslhandshakeexception-no-subject-alternative-names-present

Comment: Thanks, I saw that but I couldn't figure out how to integrate it into my project. I was hoping there would be a simpler solution that didn't involve generating keys etc.

Comment: This might help http://humandoing.net/blog/2006/03/06/java-ssl-trust-manager/

Comment: Thanks, but that's the link I posted in my question! =P It only takes you as far as connecting, which seems OK. Its actually getting the page content back which is a little tricky...

Comment: @RJ45, please don't encourage using this trust manager: it disables certificate verification and makes the connection vulnerable to MITM attacks.

Comment: @Jon, are you in control of that server?

Comment: Yes, I am testing the project locally at the moment but I am unsure how to create certificates or pass login details so that I can access the secured page. Do you know the most straight-forward way of doing this?