# How to use an HTTPS wsdl file without downloading to local computer in java

Tags: java, web-services, https, wsdl, client

I just implemented my first webservice (client). The URL is HTTPS. I tried to use the URL directly but i could not. So i downloaded the WSDL file and everything worked fine. Now the problem is that when service definition changes i will not know because the code that i wrote is based on the local WSDL i saved. So back to square one. Is it possible to use HTTPS URL directly without downloading it.
The exceptions i got while trying to implement the webservice using the URL are:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException: Failed to create service.
at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.<init>(ServiceImpl.java:151)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.spi.ProviderImpl.createServiceDelegate(ProviderImpl.java:101)
at javax.xml.ws.Service.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.tempuri.Service.<init>(Service.java:43)
at org.tempuri.ServiceSoap_ServiceSoap_Client.main(ServiceSoap_ServiceSoap_Client.java:65)
Caused by: org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException: Failed to create service.
at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLServiceFactory.<init>(WSDLServiceFactory.java:100)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.initializePorts(ServiceImpl.java:204)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.<init>(ServiceImpl.java:149)
... 4 more

Caused by: javax.wsdl.WSDLException: WSDLException: faultCode=PARSER_ERROR: Problem parsing 'https myipaddress service.asmx?WSDL'.: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative names present
at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.getDocument(WSDLReaderImpl.java:2198)
at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.readWSDL(WSDLReaderImpl.java:2390)
at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.readWSDL(WSDLReaderImpl.java:2422)
at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLManagerImpl.loadDefinition(WSDLManagerImpl.java:263)
at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLManagerImpl.getDefinition(WSDLManagerImpl.java:206)
at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLServiceFactory.<init>(WSDLServiceFactory.java:98)
... 6 more

Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative names present
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLVersionDetector.determineDocVersion(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.getDocument(WSDLReaderImpl.java:2188)
... 11 more

Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative names present
at sun.security.util.HostnameChecker.matchIP(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.util.HostnameChecker.match(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkIdentity(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(Unknown Source)
```

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer is yes it is possible to use HTTPS to retrieve the WSDL.

The "No subject alternative names present" is Java's obscure way of telling you that there is a mismatch between the hostname of the URL you are using, and the Common Name (CN) in the hosts Certificate.

The right solution is to either use the hostname that matches the certificate, or get a new certificate issued with the proper hostnames in it.

There is a work around described in [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10258101/sslhandshakeexception-no-subject-alternative-names-present%20%22this%20similar%20question%22.).