# How to disable CN checking in a Jersey Jax-rs project using cxf

Tags: java, web-services, https, cxf, jersey-client

I have/inherited a maven project that's based on JERSEY JAX-RS. I'm having and issue with disabling CN checking so that I can connect to a repository outside my control.
I have seen this [similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21120264/https-url-hostname-not-matching-common-name-cn-despite-setting-disablecncheck) and tried **-Djsse.enableSNIExtension=false** as I do have the same exact error; 
as well as adding a cxf.xml file as per specified on the [cxf site](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-rs.html#JAX-RS-HowRequestURIisMatched) but none of these work.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can try to use HostNameVerifier and force verify method to return true as an alternative.

Thanks,

Comment: Not to the resource class responsible for the call it seems, nor to the class responsible for handling cmis connections.