# How to build the EndPoint correctly using jax-ws?

Tags: java, security, ssl, https, jax-ws

I am using the bootstrap method to build my endpoints dynamically by making the WSDL available locally. For both http and https, but I am pretty sure I am going somewhere wrong while building them for https.

```
Map<String, Object> context = ((BindingProvider)control).getRequestContext();
URL address = mInstance.getConnectionEndpoint();
    if (address != null && Settings.getSettings().isUsingHttpConnection()) {
        context.put(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY,address.toString());
        System.out.println(address);
    }
    else{
        //for https

HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier()
        {
            public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session)
            {
                if (hostname.equals("myhostname"))
                    return true;
                return false;
            }
        });

        address = mInstance.getSecureConnectionEndpoint();
        context.put(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY,address.toString());
    }
```

Where getConnectionEndpoint and getSecureConnectionEndpoint look like:

```
   public URL getConnectionEndpoint() {
    URL url = null;
    try {
        int port = 50013;
        url = new URL("http", mHost.getHostAddress(), port, "");
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return url;
}

public URL getSecureConnectionEndpoint() {
    URL url = null;
    try {
        int port = 50014;
        url = new URL("https", mHost.getHostAddress(), port, "");
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return url;
}
```

This works fine when I use http. But for https I always end up getting this error that says:

```
com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.ClientTransportException: HTTP transport error: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative names present
```

Obviously googling this error I found answers that it might be due to improper importing of the server and client SSL certificates in the Java TrustStore.

But I am pretty confident that the issue is not that.

The child errors of the parent error mentioned above look something like this:

```
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(Unknown Source)
```

I would be grateful to you if you can help me solve this issue! Cheers in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is likely that the value returned from `mHost.getHostAddress()` is a different hostname than the [common name](https://support.dnsimple.com/articles/what-is-common-name/) on the certificate offered by the server.  For example, if `localhost` is the the value of `mHost.getHostAddress()` yet the SSL cert is issued to `127.0.0.1` (or vice versa) you may get this issue.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10258101/sslhandshakeexception-no-subject-alternative-names-present) identifies a code workaround in case regenerating and reinstalling the certificate with a different [CN](https://support.dnsimple.com/articles/what-is-common-name/) is not viable or desirable. It involves using the [HostnameVerifier](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/HostnameVerifier.html) mechanism of [HttpsUrlConnection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/HttpsURLConnection.html#setHostnameVerifier(javax.net.ssl.HostnameVerifier)).

Comment: Thank you, but I still get the error. Check my edit above!

Comment: Post the value being returned by `mHost.getHostAddress()` and the common name on the cert. The two must match or you may get the error you are encountering.

Comment: It worked! I was using the wrong domain name for the CN, that was the problem. But thanks for your help :)