# How to config SSL certificate for external servers in Spring Boot Tomcat?

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat7

I am creating a Spring Boot integration with Tomcat for Soap WebService application

We are calling other Soap WebServices inside it, which are running in https protocol.

Could you please help me how to config SSL for external servers?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if these external servers have their own legal trusted certificates, you don't need to do anything.

But if not and you trust these external servers, you can skip certificates verification for those servers as [How to fix the “java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative names present” error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19540289/how-to-fix-the-java-security-cert-certificateexception-no-subject-alternative/19542614#19542614).

Or just skip specific host as [SSLHandshakeException: No subject alternative names present](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10258101/sslhandshakeexception-no-subject-alternative-names-present/10296475#10296475).

Wish it could help.