# How to connect mongo db with dropwizard using SSL?

Tags: mongodb, ssl, dropwizard

I want to connect to a SSL enabled mongoDB cluster via my dropwizard service. I am unable to find relevant documentation regarding the same. I do have the .pem file with me

I have tried following: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/configure-ssl-clients/ but it only mentions the command line commands, nothing about configs: mongo --ssl --host hostname.example.com --sslCAFile /etc/ssl/ca.pem

```
    dbName: "test"
    username: "${mongo_test_user_name}"
    password: "${mongo_test_password}"
    writeConcern: "someValue"
    readPreference: "someValue"
    maxConnectionsPerHost: 10
    threadsAllowedToBlockForConnectionMultiplier: 3
    serverSelectionTimeout: -2
```

I am not sure what should I add in config and application, configuration to make this work

Comment: Check this section of the manual you have cited: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/configure-ssl-clients/#mongodb-drivers Take a closer look at the contents just after the beginning of the document. The link in the section leads to: http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.0/driver/reference/connecting/ssl/ IMO it is what you need to learn.

Comment: @zloster. Thank you, I followed it and added url - made some progress. Now I get error
```! java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative names present```. please help, how can we fix this - looks like there is something wrong with certificate common name. but I checked the certificate and it has ip address and that is what I am passing in my application

Comment: You could provide an answer to your own question detailing the steps which helped you to make progress. About the certificate problems: solving this kind of problem requires careful inspections.  Take a look for example here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10258101/sslhandshakeexception-no-subject-alternative-names-present The usual `quick and dirty hack/workaround` is the modification of the `HostnameVerifier` implementation.

Comment: @zloster Well, I just made ```sslEnabled=true``` in the url.
I checked this stackoverflow question and it does not help.
I also get ```sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target```
Please help

Comment: Search for the error message you cited. There is plenty of information about the topic.