# Android - SSL Certificate to IP - Still failing host validation

Tags: android, ssl, certificate, emulation

I'm putting together a demo web-app.

I've created a certificate signed by my own CA, and imported that CA into the android device.

I have the Android device going to:
10.0.2.2 (Which is the host machine on the emulator)

The host comes up, but its given a domain mismatch error in the browser, even though the certificate is 10.0.2.2.

Anybody know why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What Android version are you testing on? Android's hostname verifier is stricter than most browsers, and requires the IP address to be in a Subject Alternative Name entry of IP address type, not just in the CN. So either use a hostname to access your demo site, or re-create the certificate, putting the IP address in the SAN extension. If you are using OpenSSL, something like this should do it: http://andyarismendi.blogspot.in/2011/09/creating-certificates-with-sans-using.html

Comment: Sweet, that makes sense. I'll give it a shot and let you know!

I'm using 220 (Which I believe is Froyo).

Comment: Unless this is heavily customized, Froyo doesn't have the ability to import CA certificates. How did you import it?

Comment: This can be done with `keytool` too now (see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8444863/372643)).

Comment: I can confirm this works. FYI, openssl lets you add an IP address for a DNS name, and the IP name, where keytool requires a DNS name start with a letter. As a result I'm not sure if in this particular instance keytool would have worked for Android.

Comment: *"... or re-create the certificate, putting the IP address in the SAN extension"* - for instructions on doing it with OpenSSL via a CONF file (the only way to utilize SANs), see [SSL Certificate Verification: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25079751/ssl-certificate-verification-javax-net-ssl-sslhandshakeexception/25084465#25084465).