# Why does Node.js accept IP addresses in certificates only for SAN, not for CN?

Tags: node.js, ssl, ssl-certificate

As pointed out in my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14089295/1333873) to [Hostname / IP doesn't match certificate's altname](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14088787/hostname-ip-doesnt-match-certificates-altname/) Node.js does successfully verify TLS certificates on host names when the requested host name is given as the Common Name (CN) of the certificate.

```
Request    : localhost
Common Name: localhost
=> Success
```

Now when I try the same for an IP address, verification fails:

```
Request    : 192.168.178.31
Common Name: 192.168.178.31
=> Fail
```

It only works if I specify the IP address as Subject Alternative Name (SAN):

```
Request                 : 192.168.178.31
Common Name             : 192.168.178.31
Subject Alternative Name: 192.168.178.31
=> Success
```

As described in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11710762/1333873) to [IP address as hostname (CN) when creating a certificate? (HTTPS hostname wrong: should be <ipAddress>)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11708717/ip-address-as-hostname-cn-when-creating-a-certificate-https-hostname-wrong),

> using IP address in certificates is not recommended [...].

As an alternative it is suggested in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8444863/1333873) to [How are SSL certificate server names resolved/Can I add alternative names using keytool?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8443081/how-are-ssl-certificate-server-names-resolved-can-i-add-alternative-names-using) to add IP addresses as SANs (which in turn works in Node.js).

Now my question is: *Not recommended* does not mean *wrong* or *forbidden*. Is there any specific reason except being *not recommended* that Node.js does not support IP addresses in CNs, or why it would be a risk (security, whatever, ...) if it did?

Comment: I was having the exact same problem. Thanks for posting your research here in such easily digestable form - helped me to confirm my suspicions!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The implementation is merely compliant with the [HTTPS specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2818#section-3.1):

> In some cases, the URI is specified as an IP address rather than a
> hostname. In this case, the iPAddress subjectAltName must be present
> in the certificate and must exactly match the IP in the URI.

When I said "not recommended" in the answer you quote, it was more about using IP addresses in general when using HTTPS. Some browsers let you get away with it, but I also quoted the spec there, which does use the word "must". Needless to say the RFC is more authoritative than any answers you'll find here.