# Hostname / IP doesn't match certificate's altname

Tags: node.js, ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate, csr

I am trying to create a TLS server / client setup using Node.js 0.8.8 with a self-signed certificate.

The essential server code looks like

```
var tlsServer = tls.createServer({
  key: fs.readFileSync('server-key.pem'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('server-cert.pem')
}, function (connection) {
  // [...]
});
tlsServer.listen(3000);
```

Now when I try to connect to this server I use the following code:

```
var connection = tls.connect({
  host: '192.168.178.31',
  port: 3000,

  rejectUnauthorized: true,
  ca: [ fs.readFileSync('server-cert.pem') ]
}, function () {
  console.log(connection.authorized);
  console.log(connection.authorizationError);
  console.log(connection.getPeerCertificate());
});
```

If I remove the line

```
ca: [ fs.readFileSync('server-cert.pem') ]
```

from the client-side code, Node.js throws an error telling me `DEPTH_ZERO_SELF_SIGNED_CERT`. As far as I understand it this is due to the fact that it is a self-signed cert and there is no other party who trusts this certificate.

If I remove

```
rejectUnauthorized: true,
```

as well, the error is gone - but `connection.authorized` is equal to `false` which effectively means that my connection is not encrypted. Anyway, using `getPeerCertificate()` I can access the certificate sent by the server. As I want to enforce an encrypted connection, I understand that I may not remove this line.

Now I read that I can use the `ca` property to specify any CA that I want Node.js to trust. The [documentation of the TLS module](http://nodejs.org/api/tls.html#tls_tls_connect_port_host_options_callback) implies that it's enough to add the server certificate to the `ca` array, and then everything should be fine.

If I do that, this error is gone, but I get a new one:

```
Hostname/IP doesn't match certificate's altnames
```

To me this means that the CA is now basically trusted, hence that's okay now, but the certificate was made for another host than the one I use.

I created the certificate using

```
$ openssl genrsa -out server-key.pem 2048
$ openssl req -new -key server-key.pem -out server-csr.pem
$ openssl x509 -req -in server-csr.pem -signkey server-key.pem -out server-cert.pem
```

as the documentation implies. When creating the CSR I am asked the usual questions, such as for country, state, ... and common name (CN). As you are told "on the web" for an SSL certificate you do *not* provide your name as CN, but the host name you would like to use.

And this is probably where I fail.

I tried

- `localhost`
- `192.168.178.31`
- `eisbaer`
- `eisbaer.fritz.box`

where the last two are the local name and the fully qualified local name of my machine.

Any idea what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Important note: This is `Node v0.8.8`. `rejectUnauthorized` now defaults to `true`.

Comment: Your connection is [still encrypted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16311147/4068278) by default if you use `rejectUnauthorized: false`. It simply doesn't verify the identity of the host to which you're connecting which could leave you vulnerable to MITM attacks on SSL.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Recently there was an [addition to node.js](https://github.com/joyent/node/commit/bf5e2f246eff55dfc33318f0ffb4572a56f7645a) which allows overriding hostname check with a custom function. It was added to v0.11.14 and will be available in the next stable release (0.12). Now you can do something like:

```
var options = {
  host: '192.168.178.31',
  port: 3000,
  ca: [ fs.readFileSync('server-cert.pem') ],
  checkServerIdentity: function (host, cert) {
    return undefined;
  }
};
options.agent = new https.Agent(options);
var req = https.request(options, function (res) {
  //...
});
```

This will now accept any server identity, but still encrypt the connection and verify keys.

**Note** that in previous versions (e.g. `v0.11.14`), the `checkServerIdentity` was to return a `boolean` indicating the validity of the server. That has been changed (before `v4.3.1`) to the function `return`ing (not `throw`ing) an error if there is a problem and `undefined` if there is it's valid.

Comment: Being stuck in v0.10, I have [monkey-patched](https://gist.github.com/ntrrgc/c5cbff08d0033e00f503) `tls` module to skip this check. It is a very ugly fix as it is global, but it is still better than nothing.

Comment: set NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0 env var

Comment: Just to warn people: `NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED` allows you to connect to anyone, whether it be your intended server or not. The connection is encrypted, but it is not *authorized* which is often a very critical thing. And, setting it as a Global variable is a pretty heavy handed method. Just set `rejectUnauthorized` to false in your `tls` connect options.

Comment: For posterity, (v4.3.1 docs)[https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v4.x/docs/api/tls.html#tls_tls_connect_port_host_options_callback] indicate that you should `return` an `Error` if there is a problem with the server's identity, and `undefined` if the server passes the identity check. Unsure when this change happened.

Answer (score 9):

In [tls.js, lines 112-141](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/77ed12fe7a16d3d97d637512db109f4273711bec/lib/tls.js#L112-L141), you can see that if the host name used when calling `connect` is an IP address, the certificate's CN is ignored and only the SANs are being used.

As my certificate doesn't use SANs, verification fails.

Comment: I'm having this same problem, but I do have SAN for localhost and 127.0.0.1. Doesn't matter whether I connect against hostname ('localhost') or IP address ('127.0.0.1'). For me, openssl s_client connects, given all the same parameters, while tls.connect() fails.

Answer (score 7):

If you're using a host name to connect, the host name will be checked against the Subject Alternative Names of DNS type, if any, and fall back on the CN in the Subject Distinguished Name otherwise.

If you're using an IP address to connect, the IP address will be be checked against the SANs of *IP address* type, without falling back on the CN.

This is at least what implementations compliant with the [HTTP over TLS](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2818#section-3.1) specification (i.e. HTTPS) do. Some browser are a bit more tolerant.

This is exactly the same problem as in [this answer in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8444863/372643), which also gives a method to put custom SANs via OpenSSL (see [this document too](http://www.crsr.net/Notes/SSL.html)).

Generally speaking, unless it's for a test CA, it's quite hard to manage certificates that rely on IP addresses. Connecting with a host name is better.

Answer (score 3):

Mitar had a wrong assumption that checkServerIdentity should return 'true' at success, but actually it should return 'undefined' at success. Any other values are treated as error descriptions.

So such a code is correct:

```
var options = {
  host: '192.168.178.31',
  port: 3000,
  ca: [ fs.readFileSync('server-cert.pem') ],
  checkServerIdentity: function (host, cert) {
    // It can be useful to resolve both parts to IP or to Hostname (with some synchronous resolver (I wander why they did not add done() callback as the third parameter)).
    // Be carefull with SNI (when many names are bound to the same IP).
    if (host != cert.subject.CN)
      return 'Incorrect server identity';// Return error in case of failed checking.
      // Return undefined value in case of successful checking.
      // I.e. you could use empty function body to accept all CN's.
  }
};
options.agent = new https.Agent(options);
var req = https.request(options, function (res) {
  //...
});
```

I tried just to make edit in the Mitar's answer but the edit was rejected, so I created a separated answer.

Answer (score -1):

What you're doing wrong is using an IP address instead of a domain name. Create a domain name and stick it in a DNS server (or just in a hosts file), create a self-signed certificate with the domain name as the Common Name, and connect to the domain name rather than the IP address.

Comment: But it should (must?) work with IP addresses as well, shouldn't it? I do not want to set up domain names, for various reasons.