# Can I provide a list of acceptable hostnames to an SSLSocket?

Tags: python, ssl, python-3.x, openssl

I'm trying to connect to a server with a self-signed certificate and no domain name. The problem is, despite having loaded a copy of the server's certificate with `SSLContext.load_verify_locations()`, it seems to consider it invalid:

```
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:550)
```

I'm pretty sure it's just a hostname mismatch, because I'm `connect()`ing to the server's IP, and the certificate doesn't have the IP in the `Common Name` field. Is there any way to tell the `SSLSocket` “it's okay if the server's certificate is for one of these hostnames”?

Answer (score 0):

You can add your IP to the Subject Alternative Names. There's good information in [this question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14088787/hostname-ip-doesnt-match-certificates-altname)

Comment: This doesn't work if I'm not the admin of the server.

Comment: Before you disable hostname validation you could add the hostname + IP to your /etc/hosts file. I assume this is for testing.