# Encountering Hostname/IP doesn't match certificate's altnames on Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku

I'm leveraging the WePay node.js sdk https://github.com/wepay/NodeJS-SDK

When trying to communicate to WePay, I receive the error: `Hostname/IP doesn't match certificate's altnames`

This is running on Heroku and I have the SSL cert configured and it is valid for the domain that is making the request. I'm not sure if this is an issue on my end or if it is a config issue with Heroku.

Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Node.js Hostname/IP doesn't match certificate's altnames](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14262986/node-js-hostname-ip-doesnt-match-certificates-altnames)

Comment: I answered this issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14088787/hostname-ip-doesnt-match-certificates-altname/27551126#27551126

Answer (score 1):

Can you please specify the node version.Node 10.x has added security which can easy be disabled by rejectUnauthorized or process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = "0"; DONT DO IT!.

Better to add a CA in your list of CAs in http(s) global agent or in specifying ca:[cert] in http options where cert is the Certificate of CA or site you are connecting to.
Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm using node v0.10.12 and noticed that after node v.8 that ssl validation was added and caused errors like this. Thanks for the feedback, I'll try this out.