# Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative names present

Tags: java, ssl, certificate, x509, cisco-axl

We are trying the sample application in Cisco DevNet website, which demonstrates how to create an Extension Mobility web service consumer client. We have followed the instructions and imported the certification to the keystore, but it still won't work.

Here is the link of the sample: 
https://developer.cisco.com/site/extension-mobility/learn/sample-apps/index.gsp

Here is the error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative names present
```

When I test with insecure connection use the URL as

```
http:/<x.x.x.x>/:8080/emservice/EMServiceServlet
```

It shows 500 error message:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:147)
com.cisco.emservice.EMServiceServlet.processRequest(EMServiceServlet.java:204)
com.cisco.emservice.EMServiceServlet.doPost(EMServiceServlet.java:451)
com.cisco.emservice.EMServiceServlet.doGet(EMServiceServlet.java:385)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:274)
org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:271)
java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
javax.security.auth.Subject.doAsPrivileged(Subject.java:517)
org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.execute(SecurityUtil.java:306)
org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.doAsPrivilege(SecurityUtil.java:166)
```

Here is my code:

```
public class Workplace {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    URL url = new URL("https://192.168.10.11:8443/emservice/EMServiceServlet");
    URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
    conn.setDoOutput(true);
    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    String EMRequest = "<request><appinfo><appid>operator</appid><appcertificate>operator</appcertificate></appinfo>";
    EMRequest += "<login><devicename>SEP000000000001</devicename><userid>user01</userid><deviceprofile>EM-USER01/deviceprofile>";
    EMRequest += "<exclusiveduration><time>60</time></exclusiveduration></login></request>";
    //URL encode/escape the request
    EMRequest = URLEncoder.encode(EMRequest,"UTF-8");
    //Build the complete HTTP form request body
    EMRequest = "xml="+EMRequest;

    //Create an OutputStreamWriter for the URLConnection object and make the request
    OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
    writer.write(EMRequest);
    writer.flush();

    //Read the response
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));

    //Output the response to the console
    String line;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(line);
    }

    //Cleanup the stream objects
    writer.close();
    reader.close();
    }
}
```

is there any solution for this problem? Thank you...

Comment: You're trying to access an SSL-enabled web service over `http` instead of `https`.  Try using `https://:8443/emservice/EMServiceServlet` or something along those lines.

Comment: I have used the https, but it still won't work. The error message is the same as the previous one.

Comment: Can you include the Java code you used to access the URL?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/17167691/207421

Comment: There is the code that I use

Comment: Which are you asking about? The handshake exception? Or the NPE?

Comment: both but, the handshake is the most important. Thankss

Comment: The `CertificateException` happens because of the certificate on the server you are connecting to; see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10258101/sslhandshakeexception-no-subject-alternative-names-present for a similar situation.  The `setDefaultHostnameVerifier` workaround in that post might work for you.