# Self signed certificate honoring both, Machine Name & IP Address

Tags: ssl, https, iis-7.5, self-signed

I generated a self signed certificate on IIS 7.5. It got generated against the machine name. At present I am testing my website over the IP address. On accessing it on Chrome over **https** I get a message, "*You attempted to reach **IP Address**, but instead you actually reached a server identifying itself as **Machine Name***".

How can I ensure that the certificate can honor both the **Machine Name** and the **IP address**?

If in case both cannot be honored, how can I make it honor the IP address only?

Comment: Just plain entering your IP instead of your hostname in the common name field when generating your certificate should work. If you want both, [this](http://lanestechblog.blogspot.se/2009/04/creating-ssl-certificates-with-multiple.html) should work.

Comment: I am using the "Server Certificates" feature of the IIS 7.5 to create a Self Signed Certificate. The user experience to generate a certificate does not allow me to assign a common name field. Is there something I am missing? I tried looking at the SelfSSL.exe but it looks like it is only for installing a Self Signed Certificate on IIS.

Comment: You're not using [this method](http://www.digicert.com/csr-creation-microsoft-iis-7.htm)? It seems to have a step with common name.

Comment: No, I am not using the above method. This method is not creating a certificate, just a certificate request. Right now I am in a research stage where I want to function with Self Signed Certificate and not purchasing a certificate. The above link requires me to go to the digicert.com website and commercially buy a certificate. The method I am using is IIS 7.5 -> Click Machine Name -> Click Server Certificates -> Click Open Feature -> Create Self Signed Certificate

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson IP addresses shouldn't be in the CN, this is not compliant with the specs (although some browsers tolerate it).

Comment: @Bruno It should definitely not go in a public cert, but for self signed testing it should work, probably - yes - depending on browser.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson, Java clients (which follow the spec), for example, would fail, even in a testing environment.

Answer (score 4):

You should create a certificate with multiple Subject Alternative Names. What you put in the CN at that stage doesn't really matter (it's only a fallback solution when there are no SANs), but putting the host name should help you identify the certificate in various lists.

Note that the entries for host names should be of `dNSName` type, but the entries for the IP address should be of `iPAddress` type, so you need a certificate creation tool that supports both. There are more details in [this question (not specific to Java)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8444863/372643).

Note that IP addresses can be OK in a development context, but host names are often better anyway. Few (if any) CAs will issue you with a certificate tied to an IP address.