# javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertificateException

Tags: java, ssl, ssl-certificate

I have written below code. Have imported the certificate successfully. Can anyone tell me what may be the reason for getting the exception? I am trying to connect one IP https://x.x.x.x but getting the exception. I tried two things

1) By passing the certificate
2) Download the certificate and add it into the java trust store using keytool. 
For me none is working fine.

```
package com.dell;    
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;
import javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager;

public class HttpURLConnectionExample {
    private final String USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        HttpURLConnectionExample http = new HttpURLConnectionExample();
        System.out.println("Testing 1 - Send Http GET request");
        http.sendGet();
        System.out.println("\nTesting 2 - Send Http POST request");
        http.sendPost();

    }

    // HTTP GET request
    private void sendGet() throws Exception {
        URL obj = null;
        TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[] { 
                new X509TrustManager() {     
                    public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() { 
                        return null;
                    } 
                    public void checkClientTrusted( 
                        java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
                        } 
                    public void checkServerTrusted( 
                        java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
                    }
                } 
            }; 

        // Install the all-trusting trust manager
        try {
            SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
            sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());
            HttpsURLConnection
                    .setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());
        } catch (GeneralSecurityException e) {
        }
        try {
            obj = new URL("https://10.94.218.114");
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        }

        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection(); 
        con.setRequestMethod("GET");        
        con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT); 
        int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
        System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode); 
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer(); 
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();

        //print result
        System.out.println(response.toString());

    }

    // HTTP POST request
    private void sendPost() throws Exception {

        String url = "https://selfsolve.apple.com/wcResults.do";
        URL obj = new URL(url);
        HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

        //add request header
        con.setRequestMethod("POST");
        con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
        con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");

        String urlParameters = "sn=C02G8416DRJM&cn=&locale=&caller=&num=12345";

        // Send post request
        con.setDoOutput(true);
        DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
        wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);
        wr.flush();
        wr.close();

        int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
        System.out.println("\nSending 'POST' request to URL : " + url);
        System.out.println("Post parameters : " + urlParameters);
        System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();
        System.out.println(response.toString());

    }

}
```

Comment: Can you show the complete exception? It should indicate what is wrong with the certificate.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative names present
 at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
 at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(Unknown Source)
 at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)
 at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)
 at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(Unknown Source)
 at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(Unknown Source)
 at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Unknown Source)

Comment: Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative names present
 at sun.security.util.HostnameChecker.matchIP(Unknown Source)

Comment: Note that the TrustManager you are using is radically insecure. Don't deploy this as production code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is exactly the same problem as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8444863/372643). The default Java host name verifier implements [RFC 2818](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2818#section-3.1) strictly when it deals with IP addresses:

> In some cases, the URI is specified as an IP address rather than a hostname. In this case, the iPAddress subjectAltName must be present in the certificate and must exactly match the IP in the URI.

In particular, it doesn't fall back on the CN in the Subject DN when the IP address isn't found in the SAN.

Essentially, the certificate for that service is not compliant with the HTTPS specification (but some browsers will accept it anyway).

You should get in touch with whoever controls that server and ask them to put in place a certificate with a SAN entry for this IP address (note that the type of entry needs to be "IP address", not "DNS").