# How to get an XML response from an https request in Play Framework 2.2.1?

Tags: java, ssl, https, playframework, playframework-2.2

I want to get an XML response using this code (I use Java version of Play):

```
Promise<WS.Response> homePage = WS.url("https://example.com").setAuth("username", "password").get();
```

It's over SSL.

1. How do I accept any certificate or the one I need?
2. How do I actually get the response body from the promise? I haven't used it yet.

Comment: See this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19288803/trust-all-ssl-certificates-in-java-playframework-2-2) for your first question.

Comment: @Peter Thanks, but it doesn't explain how to extract the response from the `Promise`.

Comment: I only use play with scala, I don't know how it should be done in Java, but I imagine that you should listen for the onComplete or onSuccess event and then do something like this `response.body` and parse it using your XML parser.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the Java version of `Promise` has no `onComplete` method like the Scala version:

http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.1/api/java/play/libs/F.Promise.html

If you just want to (busy) wait for the result use `get()` (waits up to 5000ms) or another implementation of `get`:

http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.1/api/java/play/libs/F.Promise.html#get()