# Play Java ConnectException : GeneralSSL Exception

Tags: openssl, certificate, ssl-certificate, openid, playframework-2.2

I created an OpenID provider in nodejs for SSO in my application. 
My application is written in play framework 2.2.1 and for some reason when I try to connect to my provider with the given api in play it gives me this error : "ConnectException: GeneralSSL Exception".

My code :

```
Promise<String> prs = null;
Try {
  prs = OpenID.redirectURL(openid url, comeback url);
} catch(Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}

return redirect(prs.get());
```

I am using in my provider with a pfx file for ssl. The certificate was signed by a CA I trust.

Thanks!

P.S.
If anyone can edit my code to a code block it would be great! Im posting this through my phone..

Comment: I think you will have to provide us with more of the exception info.

Comment: Could be the same as this problem maybe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19288803/trust-all-ssl-certificates-in-java-playframework-2-2

Comment: Yes , this is the same problem. I saw this post before , and indeed it works by adding :'code' ws.acceptAnyCertificate=true
Im looking for a way to implement what @Bruno suggested.
I just dont understand how to add my certificate to my trust store.
Actually it would be great if someone get describe a little bit on what is this "trust store" and how do i install certificates in.

Comment: The keystore is a list of trusted CAs java is shipped with its default keystore
You can link to your own keystore or extend the existing one.
I think this [resource](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/java-keytool-essentials-working-with-java-keystores) can be useful.