# SSL Certificate: How to deal with Common Name and Subject Alternative Name?

Tags: ssl, certificate, ssl-certificate

I have read answers to similar questions, but this one seems a little different. The requirement of certificate here is to accommodate different types of access to server: using IP address directly and using domain name.

In such case, should I put domain name in "CN" and IP address in "SAN", will that work?

Also, how will this work under DHCP, assuming domain name remains unchanged.

Thanks for your clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I remember, you should put the IP address as one of the Subject Alternative Names (SANs). If the browser can't find the IP Address in the SANs, I don't think it is required to check the CN. You should put the Fully Qualified Domain Name (FQDN) in both the CN and the SANs.

Comment: In principle, when an IP address is used, the browser should only check the SAN, not the CN, although some browsers do it anyway. (See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8444863/372643).)