# SSL Cerficate - No subject alternative names present

Tags: java, ssl, ssl-certificate, cas

I am try to generate self sign SSL certificate but get following error in cas sso:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative names present
```

I am using open jdk 7 and used following commands:

`keytool -genkey -alias axyz -keypass changeit -keyalg RSA -ext san=ip:192.168.1.4`

`keytool -export -alias axyz -keypass changeit  -file axyz.crt`

`keytool -import -file axyz.crt -alias axyz -keystore /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/security/cacerts`

HostName: vaapdev
internal ip address: 192.168.1.4
Public IP address: 108.51.62.36

Not sure where I am going wrong, I tried both 192.168.1.4 and 108.51.62.36 in -ext
Tried without -ext parameter.

Answer (score 1):

When using a host name it's possible to fall back to the Common Name in the Subject DN of the server certificate instead of using the Subject Alternative Name.

When using an IP address there must be a Subject Alternative Name entry (of type IP address, not DNS name) in the certificate.

You'll find more details about the specification and how to generate such a certificate here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8444863/372643

Answer (score 0):

You can do 2 things here either change the CN name in self-signed certificate to match from your domain where you are running application if in case it is localhost then cn name should be localhost or else add the subject alt names as mentioned below

Please look at this [link to understand step by step](http://www.littlebigextra.com/how-to-add-subject-alt-names-or-multiple-domains-in-a-key-store-and-self-signed-certificate/).

The above error means that your JKS file is missing the required domain on which you are trying to access the application.You will need to Use Open SSL and the key tool to add multiple domains

1. Copy the openssl.cnf into a current directory
2. `echo '[ subject_alt_name ]' >> openssl.cnf`
3. `echo 'subjectAltName = DNS:example.mydomain1.com, DNS:example.mydomain2.com, DNS:example.mydomain3.com, DNS: localhost'>> openssl.cnf`
4. `openssl req -x509 -nodes -newkey rsa:2048 -config openssl.cnf -extensions subject_alt_name -keyout private.key -out self-signed.pem -subj '/C=gb/ST=edinburgh/L=edinburgh/O=mygroup/OU=servicing/CN=www.example.com/emailAddress=postmaster@example.com' -days 365`
5. Export the public key (.pem) file to PKS12 format. This will prompt you for password

   ```
   openssl pkcs12 -export -keypbe PBE-SHA1-3DES -certpbe PBE-SHA1-3DES -export -in
   self-signed.pem -inkey private.key -name myalias -out keystore.p12
   ```
6. Create a.JKS from self-signed PEM (Keystore)

   ```
   keytool -importkeystore -destkeystore keystore.jks -deststoretype PKCS12 -srcstoretype PKCS12 -srckeystore keystore.p12
   ```
7. Generate a Certificate from above Keystore or JKS file

   ```
   keytool -export -keystore keystore.jks -alias myalias -file selfsigned.crt
   ```
8. Since the above certificate is Self Signed and is not validated by CA, it needs to be added in Truststore(Cacerts file in below location for MAC, for Windows, find out where your JDK is installed.)

   ```
   sudo keytool -importcert -file selfsigned.crt -alias myalias -keystore /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_171.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/security/cacerts
   ```

Original answer posted  [on this link here](http://www.littlebigextra.com/how-to-add-subject-alt-names-or-multiple-domains-in-a-key-store-and-self-signed-certificate/).