# moving from http to https: javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException

Tags: linux, apache, ssl, https, ssl-certificate

Previously we were having "http" based webservice deployed on server, but now we are trying to make it https. So for this I have transferred my project from /var/www/ to /var/www-ssl on linux machine. We are using self signed certificate for https. I have configured ports.conf file of apache as follows

```
# If you just change the port or add more ports here, you will likely also
# have to change the VirtualHost statement in
# /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default
# This is also true if you have upgraded from before 2.2.9-3 (i.e. from
# Debian etch). See /usr/share/doc/apache2.2-common/NEWS.Debian.gz and
# README.Debian.gz

NameVirtualHost 0.0.0.0:8091

Listen 8091

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    # If you add NameVirtualHost *:443 here, you will also have to change
    # the VirtualHost statement in /etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl
    # to <VirtualHost *:443>
    # Server Name Indication for SSL named virtual hosts is currently not
    # supported by MSIE on Windows XP.
    Listen 8088
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/server.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/server.key
</IfModule>

<VirtualHost 172.16.1.104:8088>

    DocumentRoot /var/www-ssl
    SSLEngine On
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/server.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/server.key
</VirtualHost>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
    Listen 443
</IfModule>
```

.
Previously I was getting Subject Alternate Not Found exception, then I reconfigured the certificate with SAN and the exception gone. 
Please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22505312/certificateexception-no-subject-alternative-names-present/22549080#22549080). But Now I am getting Following exception:
javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't find  in '/var/www-ssl/ingram/wsdls/deviceprofileInfoAnother.wsdl'

I am not getting where I am going wrong. Is it server side problem or certificate problem.
Please help me through this.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by myself. *.wsdl file was containing wrong code. Now working correctly..