# Cannot successfully deploy war file in tomcat using jenkins

Tags: tomcat, grails, jenkins

I have `tomcat 7.0.39` installed in a server accessed via `https`. I have successfully deployed and currently accessing `jenkins v1.575`. I am using SVN for jenkins to checkout the latest copy of my `grails` project, build and deploy it in the server where tomcat is also running. I have also installed the `Deploy Plugin` to make it possible for jenkins to deploy war file in a container.

Below is the Post-build actions:

[image]

Creating a new build was successful, but whenever jenkins is trying to deploy its built war file, I am getting this error.

```
|Done creating WAR target/doe-lubes-0.1.war
Deploying /var/www/tomcat/.jenkins/jobs/doe-lubes/workspace/target/doe-lubes-0.1.war to container Tomcat 7.x Remote
ERROR: Publisher hudson.plugins.deploy.DeployPublisher aborted due to exception
org.codehaus.cargo.container.ContainerException: Failed to redeploy [/var/www/tomcat/.jenkins/jobs/doe-lubes/workspace/target/doe-lubes-0.1.war]
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.redeploy(AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.java:193)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter.deploy(CargoContainerAdapter.java:73)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter$1.invoke(CargoContainerAdapter.java:116)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter$1.invoke(CargoContainerAdapter.java:103)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:922)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:895)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter.redeploy(CargoContainerAdapter.java:103)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.DeployPublisher.perform(DeployPublisher.java:61)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$3.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:45)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:772)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:736)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.post2(Build.java:183)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:685)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1765)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:234)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative names present
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.invoke(TomcatManager.java:534)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.list(TomcatManager.java:686)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.getStatus(TomcatManager.java:699)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.redeploy(AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.java:174)
```

I cant find the right solution and walkthrough for this since I am still new to jenkins. I can successfully deploy war files in tomcat manually, but using jenkins, I can't.
What do I need to configure to fix this?

thanks.

Comment: Did you try out the suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Your issue seems to be related to SSL certificate as stated in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8443081/how-are-ssl-certificate-server-names-resolved-can-i-add-alternative-names-using/8444863#8444863). Approach to resolving it depends on whether you're using Java `keytool` or `OpenSSL` for generating certificate.

It suggests using `-ext` option while generating certificate. *Preferably, you should be using Hostname instead of IP*.

For certificate generation using *keytool*, you can use [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/605843/unable-to-generate-certificate-with-subject-alternate-name-using-java-1-7-keytoo) link. For OpenSSL, you will have to make changes to `openssl.cnf` file which is usually present in `/etc/ssl` directory.

Answer (score -1):

Changing your tomcat URL from https to http will fix this problem. I guess your tomcat server isn't really running in https.

Comment: In production environment Tomcat may run only in https