# CAS - Pac4J - SSLHandshakeException

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, ssl, cas

I try to run two Java applications on server accessed by IP address.

The first one is CAS  Server deployed to Tomcat instance which is installed on mentioned server. To support SSO I need to run HTTPS/SSL. Here everything works fine – I can access server via HTTPS without exceptions.

The second one is my application configured to use CAS Server as an identity provider. It doesn’t require HTTPS. Application is ran on Spring Embedded Tomcat.

When I open protected part of application I get redirection to CAS login page. After submitting login form I get redirection to application (/callback). As you can see everything on CAS Server’s side is OK – ticked is created and user is redirected. After redirection to /callback I get an exception:

```
2015-12-20 13:14:10 ERROR CommonUtils:442 - java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative names present
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative names present
        at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1916)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:279)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:273)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1469)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:213)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:901)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:837)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1035)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1344)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1371)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1355)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:563)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1301)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:254)
        at org.jasig.cas.client.util.CommonUtils.getResponseFromServer(CommonUtils.java:431)
        at org.jasig.cas.client.validation.AbstractCasProtocolUrlBasedTicketValidator.retrieveResponseFromServer(AbstractCasProtocolUrlBasedTicketValidator.java:41)
        at org.jasig.cas.client.validation.AbstractUrlBasedTicketValidator.validate(AbstractUrlBasedTicketValidator.java:193)
        at org.pac4j.cas.client.CasClient.retrieveUserProfile(CasClient.java:320)
        at org.pac4j.cas.client.CasClient.retrieveUserProfile(CasClient.java:83)
        at org.pac4j.core.client.BaseClient.getUserProfile(BaseClient.java:99)
        at org.pac4j.core.client.BaseClient.getUserProfile(BaseClient.java:48)
        at org.pac4j.springframework.web.CallbackController.callback(CallbackController.java:81)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:776)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:705)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:967)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:858)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:843)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.sitemesh.webapp.contentfilter.ContentBufferingFilter.bufferAndPostProcess(ContentBufferingFilter.java:169)
        at org.sitemesh.webapp.contentfilter.ContentBufferingFilter.doFilter(ContentBufferingFilter.java:126)
        at org.sitemesh.webapp.SiteMeshFilter.doFilter(SiteMeshFilter.java:120)
        at org.sitemesh.config.ConfigurableSiteMeshFilter.doFilter(ConfigurableSiteMeshFilter.java:163)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:85)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1526)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1482)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative names present
        at sun.security.util.HostnameChecker.matchIP(HostnameChecker.java:142)
        at sun.security.util.HostnameChecker.match(HostnameChecker.java:91)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkIdentity(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:347)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:203)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:126)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1451)
        ... 66 more
```

Both applications work fine on my personal computer where I use ‘localhost’ alias – I don’t need any certs for application.

On server:

1. Certificate for Tomcat: cn=localhost. Added to cacerts with alias ‘tomcat’.
2. Creating certificate for application, cn=localhost

2.1

```
$JAVA_HOME/bin/keytool -genkey -alias communicator -keyalg RSA
```

2.2

```
$JAVA_HOME/bin/keytool -export -alias communicator -file communicator.cer -keystore ~/.keystore
```

2.3

```
$JAVA_HOME/bin/keytool -import -file /etc/ssl/certs/java/ communicator.cer -keypass changeit -keystore /etc/ssl/certs/java/cacerts -alias communicator
```

I guess something is wrong with alias for application. I tried to add this certificate to cacerts as “localhost” and “hostname of my server”. Nothing changed. The only difference between server and my developer environment is IP adress instead of 'localhost' alias.

Do you have any ideas why this solution doesn’t work?

**EDIT 09.01.2015**

I’ve solved problem. The main mistake was creating and importing certificate from wrong keystore:
1.  Tomcat is configured to use /home/.keystore
2.  I tried to create cert using /root/.keystore and importing created cert to cacerts

I found solution during analysing certificate used by browser – there wasn’t any information about IP.

**Solution**

1. Generate certificate (Tomcat is configured to use /home/.keystore):

   ```
   $JAVA_HOME/bin/keytool –genkey –alias tomcat –keyalg RSA –keystore /home/.keystore –ext san=ip:{server_ip}
   ```
2. Export certificate to file:

   ```
   $JAVA_HOME/bin/keytool –export –alias tomcat –file /home/tomcat.cer –keystore /home/.keystore
   ```
3. Import exported certificate to cacerts:

   ```
   $JAVA_HOME/bin/keytool –import –alias tomcat –file /home/tomcat.cer –keystore /etc/ssl/certs/java/cacerts
   ```

Now everything should work.

Answer (score 0):

What is the url used to call your CAS server? I mean your CasClient configuration in pac4j?

Comment: CAS Server host: `https://<ip>:8443/cas/login`          
CAS Server login url: `https://<ip>:8443/cas/login?service=http://<ip>:8081/callback?client_name=CasClient`           
Application host: `http://<ip>:8081`

Comment: I've seen several questions on SO for this, especially: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8443081/how-are-ssl-certificate-server-names-resolved-can-i-add-alternative-names-using/8444863#8444863. I think you need this option when using keytool: -ext san=ip:<ip>

Comment: I deleted old certificate from cecerts, created new with -ext san=ip:<ip>, imported to cacerts - nothing changed. When I list ' -keystore /etc/ssl/certs/java/cacerts -list -v -alias tomcat
' I see SubjectAlternativeName [ IPAddress: <ip> ]'. To be 100% sure I restarted tomcat and application instance. Should I create any certificate for application?