# The certificate for this site does not contain a Subject Alternative Name extension containing a domain name or IP address?

Tags: ssl, https

I have generated a self signed certificate using openSSL following commands 
in my ubuntu based pc.

```
openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem -pubkey -days 365  -subj "/C=NZ/ST=LH/O=SoN, Inc./CN=10.16.1.96" -reqexts Canada -config <(cat /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf <(printf "[Wellington]\nsubjectAltName=DNS:10.16.1.96,DNS:10.16.1.96"))
```

Next, I have copied the private key and cert.pem in the raspberrypi(10.16.1.96) which is running a webserver and using these keys.

Also, I have added the cert.pem in my chrome browser - Manage Certificates/Authorities, I have imported this certificate.

However, my browser complains about this -

```
Subject Alternative Name missing
The certificate for this site does not contain a Subject Alternative Name extension containing a domain name or IP address.

Certificate error
There are issues with the site's certificate chain (net::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID).
```

How can I get rid of this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the end of your command, you're providing subject alternative names like this: `subjectAltName=DNS:10.16.1.96,DNS:10.16.1.96"`.

The problem is that you're using SANs of type `dNSName` (`DNS:` in the OpenSSL configuration), but you're using IP addresses, so you you need SANs of type `iPAddress` in this case (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8444863/372643) more details about the specifications).

Changing your command to use `subjectAltName=IP:10.16.1.96,IP:10.16.1.96"` should fix it.